# C# remount USB devices

Tags: c#, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programatically unplug & replug an arbitrary USB device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138394/how-to-programatically-unplug-replug-an-arbitrary-usb-device)

I have a USB device that sometimes 'gets lost' (just doesn't work anymore, probably because the driver or the product itself is not so good). however, an application I write relies on this device. what i need to do to get the device working again is plugging it out and in again.

I want to know whether i can do that somehow automatically from my C# application? like disabling and reenabling the usb port?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, under windows, you might not be able to  physically simulate the device remove and plug in back, but you can try disable the device and then enable it.

take a look at the SetupApi.dll

regarding how to do that in C# you can take a look at the following link

[Win32 API function to programatically enable/disable device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438371/win32-api-function-to-programatically-enable-disable-device)