# How do you programmatically eject an USB mass storage device?

Tags: winapi

How do you programmatically eject(safely remove) an USB mass storage device in Windows (XP)?

Answer (score 2):

In [[image] autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/), you have a [script](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=48585) which does just that.

It basically comes from this [Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B165721&x=18&y=13) and uses kernel32.dll DeviceIoControl function

Of course, this question appears to be a duplicate of [Safe remove USB-Drive using Win32 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85649/safe-remove-usb-drive-using-win32-api), which gives other solutions

Answer (score 2):

First download de code from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13530/Eject-USB-disks-using-C

Then import the classes of the folder "Library" to your project

And put this code into your click button.

```
private void btnExpulsar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Expulsa todas las unidades
            VolumeDeviceClass volumeDeviceClass = new VolumeDeviceClass();  //Enlista las unidades
            foreach (var item in volumeDeviceClass.Devices.ToList())
            {
                if (item.IsUsb)//Verifica que sean unidades USB
                {
                    item.Eject(true); //Expulsa las unidades
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't you need to put volumeDeviceClass inside a using (since this is a IDispossable implementing class)

Answer (score 1):

You could spawn a process and use a [command line tool](http://quick.mixnmojo.com/readmes/USBDiskEjector.html). This would also work from other languages such as java where calling the Win32 api is harder.