# How to get the Drive Letter for the DevicePath

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using Win32 API.

Really i do not understand how to get the drive letter for DevicePath of a USB stick .

can you pls explain it to me

( what i have is SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA DevicePath

using this Device path i get VID AND PID of the usb device

my device path looks like below

"\?\usb#vid_1a8d&pid_1000#358094020874450#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}"

Is there any way to to map DRIVE LETTER to my DEVICE PATH

so please help me to map drive letter to DevicePath )

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think this might be slightly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733206/find-which-drive-corresponds-to-which-usb-mass-storage-device-in-winxp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [link](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/system/RemoveDriveByLetter.aspx) I provided in your other question gives you all the information you need to do this.  In semi-pseudocode:

```
DiskDevice = CreateFile(DiskDevicePath);
DiskDeviceNumber = DeviceIoControl(DiskDevice, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER);
for each VolumeDevicePath in GetLogicalDriveStrings
    VolumeDevice = CreateFile(VolumeDevicePath);
    VolumeDeviceNumber = DeviceIoControl(VolumeDevice, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER);
    if(VolumeDeviceNumber == DiskDeviceNumber)
        // volume (i.e. "G:") corresponding to VolumeDevicePath resides on disk (i.e. "XYZ USB Storage Device") corresponding to DiskDevicePath
```

I'm not 100% sure (it's been a while), but I think that the Disk device (GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK) is a child of the USB device (GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE).  In any event, I think DiskDevicePath needs to be the path of the Disk device (not the USB device).

Comment: How do he get the device path, I get it from drive letter by `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA` and there is no vid and pid. I got string like `"\\?\usbstor#disk&ven_usb&prod_sg_flash&rev_1.00#________________&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91e"`

Comment: I am using GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK, so can't get vid pid, but I need from drive letter to vid pid.

Comment: GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK truly is a child of GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this, maybe it'll help (I don't think there's an easy way to do it ...)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc542456(VS.85).aspx