# Get information about disk drives result on windows7 - 32 bit system

Tags: windows, winapi, msdn

When i run the below code on windows XP - 32 , i get the below result.

i have plugged only one usb pen drive

```
On Windows XP - 32 Bit
-----------------------

Drive C:
    ProductId: ST3160215AS
    ProductRevision: 3.AAD
    DeviceType: 7, DeviceNumber: 0, PartitionNumber: 1
    DevicePath: \\?\ide#diskst3160215as_____________________________3.aad___#5&2
7db0ed4&0&0.0.0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
    Class: DiskDrive
    Hardware ID: IDE\DiskST3160215AS_____________________________3.AAD___
    Friendly Name: ST3160215AS
    Physical Device Object Name: \Device\Ide\IdeDeviceP2T0L0-5
    Device Description: Disk drive
    Parent Device Instance ID: PCIIDE\IDECHANNEL\4&1C1E8A11&0&0
    Parent of Parent Device Instance ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_27C0&SUBSYS_72671462&R
EV_01\3&11583659&0&FA
    DeviceInstanceId: IDE\DISKST3160215AS_____________________________3.AAD___\5
&27DB0ED4&0&0.0.0
Drive D:
    ProductId: ST3160215AS
    ProductRevision: 3.AAD
    DeviceType: 7, DeviceNumber: 0, PartitionNumber: 2
    DevicePath: \\?\ide#diskst3160215as_____________________________3.aad___#5&2
7db0ed4&0&0.0.0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
    Class: DiskDrive
    Hardware ID: IDE\DiskST3160215AS_____________________________3.AAD___
    Friendly Name: ST3160215AS
    Physical Device Object Name: \Device\Ide\IdeDeviceP2T0L0-5
    Device Description: Disk drive
    Parent Device Instance ID: PCIIDE\IDECHANNEL\4&1C1E8A11&0&0
    Parent of Parent Device Instance ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_27C0&SUBSYS_72671462&R
EV_01\3&11583659&0&FA
    DeviceInstanceId: IDE\DISKST3160215AS_____________________________3.AAD___\5
&27DB0ED4&0&0.0.0
Drive E:
    ProductId: ST3160215AS
    ProductRevision: 3.AAD
    DeviceType: 7, DeviceNumber: 0, PartitionNumber: 3
    DevicePath: \\?\ide#diskst3160215as_____________________________3.aad___#5&2
7db0ed4&0&0.0.0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
    Class: DiskDrive
    Hardware ID: IDE\DiskST3160215AS_____________________________3.AAD___
    Friendly Name: ST3160215AS
    Physical Device Object Name: \Device\Ide\IdeDeviceP2T0L0-5
    Device Description: Disk drive
    Parent Device Instance ID: PCIIDE\IDECHANNEL\4&1C1E8A11&0&0
    Parent of Parent Device Instance ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_27C0&SUBSYS_72671462&R
EV_01\3&11583659&0&FA
    DeviceInstanceId: IDE\DISKST3160215AS_____________________________3.AAD___\5
&27DB0ED4&0&0.0.0
Drive F:
    ProductId: ST3160215AS
    ProductRevision: 3.AAD
    DeviceType: 7, DeviceNumber: 0, PartitionNumber: 4
    DevicePath: \\?\ide#diskst3160215as_____________________________3.aad___#5&2
7db0ed4&0&0.0.0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
    Class: DiskDrive
    Hardware ID: IDE\DiskST3160215AS_____________________________3.AAD___
    Friendly Name: ST3160215AS
    Physical Device Object Name: \Device\Ide\IdeDeviceP2T0L0-5
    Device Description: Disk drive
    Parent Device Instance ID: PCIIDE\IDECHANNEL\4&1C1E8A11&0&0
    Parent of Parent Device Instance ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_27C0&SUBSYS_72671462&R
EV_01\3&11583659&0&FA
    DeviceInstanceId: IDE\DISKST3160215AS_____________________________3.AAD___\5
&27DB0ED4&0&0.0.0
Drive G:
    VendorId: JetFlash
    ProductId: Transcend 2GB
    ProductRevision: 8.07
    DeviceType: 7, DeviceNumber: 1, PartitionNumber: 1
    DevicePath: \\?\usbstor#disk&ven_jetflash&prod_transcend_2gb&rev_8.07#e3o29u
13&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
    Class: DiskDrive
    Hardware ID: USBSTOR\DiskJetFlashTranscend_2GB___8.07
    Friendly Name: JetFlash Transcend 2GB USB Device
    Physical Device Object Name: \Device\00000080
    Device Description: Disk drive
    Parent Device Instance ID: USB\VID_058F&PID_6387\E3O29U13
    Parent of Parent Device Instance ID: USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&2B6971CE&0
    DeviceInstanceId: USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_JETFLASH&PROD_TRANSCEND_2GB&REV_8.07\E3O2
9U13&0
    Drive G: is removeable
Drive X:

When i run the below code on windows7 - 32 , i get the below result

i have plugged the same usb pen drive which is used on windows xp - 32 bit...

On Windows 7 - 32 Bit
-----------------------

Drive C:
    ProductId: Hitachi HDS721616PLA380
    ProductRevision: P22OAB3A
    DeviceType: 7, DeviceNumber: 0, PartitionNumber: 2
    DevicePath: \\?\ide#diskhitachi_hds721616pla380_________________p22oab3a#5&4
be38f&0&0.0.0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
    Class: DiskDrive
    Hardware ID: USBSTOR\DiskJetFlashTranscend_2GB___8.07
    Friendly Name: JetFlash Transcend 2GB USB Device
    Physical Device Object Name: \Device\0000006f
    Device Description: Disk drive
    Parent Device Instance ID: USB\VID_058F&PID_6387\E3O29U13
    Parent of Parent Device Instance ID: USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&4E31217&0
    DeviceInstanceId: USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_JETFLASH&PROD_TRANSCEND_2GB&REV_8.07\E3O2
9U13&0
    Drive C: is removeable
Drive D:
    ProductId: Hitachi HDS721616PLA380
    ProductRevision: P22OAB3A
    DeviceType: 7, DeviceNumber: 0, PartitionNumber: 3
    DevicePath: \\?\ide#diskhitachi_hds721616pla380_________________p22oab3a#5&4
be38f&0&0.0.0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
    Class: DiskDrive
    Hardware ID: USBSTOR\DiskJetFlashTranscend_2GB___8.07
    Friendly Name: JetFlash Transcend 2GB USB Device
    Physical Device Object Name: \Device\0000006f
    Device Description: Disk drive
    Parent Device Instance ID: USB\VID_058F&PID_6387\E3O29U13
    Parent of Parent Device Instance ID: USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&4E31217&0
    DeviceInstanceId: USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_JETFLASH&PROD_TRANSCEND_2GB&REV_8.07\E3O2
9U13&0
    Drive D: is removeable
Drive E:
    ProductId: Hitachi HDS721616PLA380
    ProductRevision: P22OAB3A
    DeviceType: 7, DeviceNumber: 0, PartitionNumber: 4
    DevicePath: \\?\ide#diskhitachi_hds721616pla380_________________p22oab3a#5&4
be38f&0&0.0.0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
    Class: DiskDrive
    Hardware ID: USBSTOR\DiskJetFlashTranscend_2GB___8.07
    Friendly Name: JetFlash Transcend 2GB USB Device
    Physical Device Object Name: \Device\0000006f
    Device Description: Disk drive
    Parent Device Instance ID: USB\VID_058F&PID_6387\E3O29U13
    Parent of Parent Device Instance ID: USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&4E31217&0
    DeviceInstanceId: USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_JETFLASH&PROD_TRANSCEND_2GB&REV_8.07\E3O2
9U13&0
    Drive E: is removeable
Drive F:
    ProductId: Hitachi HDS721616PLA380
    ProductRevision: P22OAB3A
    DeviceType: 7, DeviceNumber: 0, PartitionNumber: 5
    DevicePath: \\?\ide#diskhitachi_hds721616pla380_________________p22oab3a#5&4
be38f&0&0.0.0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
    Class: DiskDrive
    Hardware ID: USBSTOR\DiskJetFlashTranscend_2GB___8.07
    Friendly Name: JetFlash Transcend 2GB USB Device
    Physical Device Object Name: \Device\0000006f
    Device Description: Disk drive
    Parent Device Instance ID: USB\VID_058F&PID_6387\E3O29U13
    Parent of Parent Device Instance ID: USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&4E31217&0
    DeviceInstanceId: USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_JETFLASH&PROD_TRANSCEND_2GB&REV_8.07\E3O2
9U13&0
    Drive F: is removeable
Drive G:
    VendorId: JetFlash
    ProductId: Transcend 2GB
    ProductRevision: 8.07
    DeviceType: 7, DeviceNumber: 1, PartitionNumber: 1
    DevicePath: \\?\usbstor#disk&ven_jetflash&prod_transcend_2gb&rev_8.07#e3o29u
13&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
    Class: DiskDrive
    Hardware ID: IDE\DiskHitachi_HDS721616PLA380_________________P22OAB3A
    Friendly Name: Hitachi HDS721616PLA380 ATA Device
    Physical Device Object Name: \Device\Ide\IdeDeviceP1T0L0-1
    Device Description: Disk drive
    Parent Device Instance ID: PCIIDE\IDECHANNEL\4&35CD87E&0&0
    Parent of Parent Device Instance ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_27C0&SUBSYS_27C08086&R
EV_01\3&2411E6FE&1&FA
    DeviceInstanceId: IDE\DISKHITACHI_HDS721616PLA380_________________P22OAB3A\5
&4BE38F&0&0.0.0
    Drive G: is removeable
Drive Z:
```

> Blockquote

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Kindly look at the both the results...

I have plugged a same usb device on both the systems ( xp and windows7 ) but the results varies...

please check the Drive G: results on the both the Os...

```
Drive G: ( On Windows 7 - 32 bit )
-----------------------------------

VendorId: JetFlash
    ProductId: Transcend 2GB
    ProductRevision: 8.07
    DeviceType: 7, DeviceNumber: 1, PartitionNumber: 1
    DevicePath: \\?\usbstor#disk&ven_jetflash&prod_transcend_2gb&rev_8.07#e3o29u
13&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
    Class: DiskDrive
    Hardware ID: IDE\DiskHitachi_HDS721616PLA380_________________P22OAB3A
    Friendly Name: Hitachi HDS721616PLA380 ATA Device
    Physical Device Object Name: \Device\Ide\IdeDeviceP1T0L0-1
    Device Description: Disk drive
    Parent Device Instance ID: PCIIDE\IDECHANNEL\4&35CD87E&0&0
    Parent of Parent Device Instance ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_27C0&SUBSYS_27C08086&R
EV_01\3&2411E6FE&1&FA
    DeviceInstanceId: IDE\DISKHITACHI_HDS721616PLA380_________________P22OAB3A\5
&4BE38F&0&0.0.0
    Drive G: is removeable

Drive G: ( On Windows XP - 32 bit )
-----------------------------------
VendorId: JetFlash
    ProductId: Transcend 2GB
    ProductRevision: 8.07
    DeviceType: 7, DeviceNumber: 1, PartitionNumber: 1
    DevicePath: \\?\usbstor#disk&ven_jetflash&prod_transcend_2gb&rev_8.07#e3o29u
13&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
    Class: DiskDrive
    Hardware ID: USBSTOR\DiskJetFlashTranscend_2GB___8.07
    Friendly Name: JetFlash Transcend 2GB USB Device
    Physical Device Object Name: \Device\00000080
    Device Description: Disk drive
    Parent Device Instance ID: USB\VID_058F&PID_6387\E3O29U13
    Parent of Parent Device Instance ID: USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&2B6971CE&0
    DeviceInstanceId: USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_JETFLASH&PROD_TRANSCEND_2GB&REV_8.07\E3O2
9U13&0
    Drive G: is removeable
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I wrote a program in C which demonstrate how to receive the information which you need

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <devguid.h>    // for GUID_DEVCLASS_CDROM etc
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <cfgmgr32.h>   // for MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN, CM_Get_Parent and CM_Get_Device_ID
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr)     (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))

#pragma comment (lib, "setupapi.lib")

//
// Define the various device characteristics flags (defined in wdm.h)
//
#define FILE_REMOVABLE_MEDIA                    0x00000001
#define FILE_READ_ONLY_DEVICE                   0x00000002
#define FILE_FLOPPY_DISKETTE                    0x00000004
#define FILE_WRITE_ONCE_MEDIA                   0x00000008
#define FILE_REMOTE_DEVICE                      0x00000010
#define FILE_DEVICE_IS_MOUNTED                  0x00000020
#define FILE_VIRTUAL_VOLUME                     0x00000040
#define FILE_AUTOGENERATED_DEVICE_NAME          0x00000080
#define FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN                 0x00000100
#define FILE_CHARACTERISTIC_PNP_DEVICE          0x00000800
#define FILE_CHARACTERISTIC_TS_DEVICE           0x00001000
#define FILE_CHARACTERISTIC_WEBDAV_DEVICE       0x00002000

#pragma warning (disable: 4201)
typedef struct _IO_STATUS_BLOCK {
    union {
        NTSTATUS Status;
        PVOID Pointer;
    } DUMMYUNIONNAME;

    ULONG_PTR Information;
} IO_STATUS_BLOCK, *PIO_STATUS_BLOCK;
#pragma warning (default: 4201)

typedef enum _FSINFOCLASS {
    FileFsVolumeInformation       = 1,
    FileFsLabelInformation,      // 2
    FileFsSizeInformation,       // 3
    FileFsDeviceInformation,     // 4
    FileFsAttributeInformation,  // 5
    FileFsControlInformation,    // 6
    FileFsFullSizeInformation,   // 7
    FileFsObjectIdInformation,   // 8
    FileFsDriverPathInformation, // 9
    FileFsVolumeFlagsInformation,// 10
    FileFsMaximumInformation
} FS_INFORMATION_CLASS, *PFS_INFORMATION_CLASS;

typedef struct _FILE_FS_DEVICE_INFORMATION {
    DEVICE_TYPE DeviceType;
    ULONG Characteristics;
} FILE_FS_DEVICE_INFORMATION, *PFILE_FS_DEVICE_INFORMATION;

typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI *LPFN_NT_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION_FILE) (HANDLE FileHandle,
                                                                 PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
                                                                 PVOID FsInformation, ULONG Length,
                                                                 FS_INFORMATION_CLASS FsInformationClass);

BOOL GetDriveTypeAndCharacteristics (HANDLE hDevice, DEVICE_TYPE *pDeviceType, ULONG *pCharacteristics)
{
    HMODULE hNtDll;
    LPFN_NT_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION_FILE lpfnNtQueryVolumeInformationFile;
    NTSTATUS ntStatus;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock;
    FILE_FS_DEVICE_INFORMATION FileFsDeviceInfo;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    hNtDll = GetModuleHandle (TEXT("ntdll.dll"));
    if (hNtDll == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    lpfnNtQueryVolumeInformationFile = (LPFN_NT_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION_FILE)GetProcAddress (hNtDll, "NtQueryVolumeInformationFile");
    if (lpfnNtQueryVolumeInformationFile == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    ntStatus = lpfnNtQueryVolumeInformationFile (hDevice, &IoStatusBlock,
                                                 &FileFsDeviceInfo, sizeof(FileFsDeviceInfo),
                                                 FileFsDeviceInformation);
    if (ntStatus == NO_ERROR) {
        bSuccess = TRUE;
        *pDeviceType = FileFsDeviceInfo.DeviceType;
        *pCharacteristics = FileFsDeviceInfo.Characteristics;
    }

    return bSuccess;
}

void FildVolumeName (LPCTSTR pszDeviceName)
{
    TCHAR szVolumeName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("");
    TCHAR szDeviceName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("");
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    DWORD dwCharCount;
    BOOL bSuccess;

    hFind = FindFirstVolume (szVolumeName, ARRAYSIZE(szVolumeName));
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return;

    while(TRUE) {
        //  Skip the \\?\ prefix and remove the trailing backslash.
        size_t Index = lstrlen(szVolumeName) - 1;
        if (szVolumeName[0]     != TEXT('\\') ||
            szVolumeName[1]     != TEXT('\\') ||
            szVolumeName[2]     != TEXT('?')  ||
            szVolumeName[3]     != TEXT('\\') ||
            szVolumeName[Index] != TEXT('\\')) return; // error

        //  QueryDosDeviceW doesn't allow a trailing backslash,
        //  so temporarily remove it.
        szVolumeName[Index] = TEXT('\0');
        dwCharCount = QueryDosDevice (&szVolumeName[4], szDeviceName, ARRAYSIZE(szDeviceName));
        szVolumeName[Index] = TEXT('\\');
        if (dwCharCount == 0) return; // error

        if (lstrcmp (pszDeviceName, szDeviceName) == 0) {
            _tprintf (TEXT("    Volume Device Name: %s\n"), szVolumeName);
            return;
        }

        bSuccess = FindNextVolume (hFind, szVolumeName, ARRAYSIZE(szVolumeName));
        if (!bSuccess) {
            DWORD dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
            if (dwErrorCode == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
                break;
            else 
                break;  // ERROR!!!
        }
    }
}

void DumpVidPidMi (LPCTSTR pszDeviceInstanceId)
{
    TCHAR szDeviceInstanceId[MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN];
    const static LPCTSTR arPrefix[3] = {TEXT("VID_"), TEXT("PID_"), TEXT("MI_")};
    LPTSTR pszToken, pszNextToken;
    int j;

    lstrcpy (szDeviceInstanceId, pszDeviceInstanceId);

    pszToken = _tcstok_s (szDeviceInstanceId , TEXT("\\#&"), &pszNextToken);
    while(pszToken != NULL) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (_tcsncmp(pszToken, arPrefix[j], lstrlen(arPrefix[j])) == 0) {
                switch(j) {
                    case 0:
                        _tprintf (TEXT("        vid: \"%s\"\n"), pszToken + lstrlen(arPrefix[j]));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        _tprintf (TEXT("        pid: \"%s\"\n"), pszToken + lstrlen(arPrefix[j]));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        _tprintf (TEXT("        mi: \"%s\"\n"), pszToken + lstrlen(arPrefix[j]));
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        pszToken = _tcstok_s (NULL, TEXT("\\#&"), &pszNextToken);
    }
}

BOOL FindDiInfos (LPCGUID pGuidInferface, LPCGUID pGuidClass, LPCTSTR pszEnumerator,
                  DEVICE_TYPE DeviceType, DWORD DeviceNumber,
                  DWORD dwDeviceInstanceIdSize,     // MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN
                  OUT LPTSTR pszDeviceInstanceId,
                  OUT PDWORD pdwRemovalPolicy)
//#define CM_REMOVAL_POLICY_EXPECT_NO_REMOVAL             1
//#define CM_REMOVAL_POLICY_EXPECT_ORDERLY_REMOVAL        2
//#define CM_REMOVAL_POLICY_EXPECT_SURPRISE_REMOVAL       3
{
    HDEVINFO hIntDevInfo = NULL;
    DWORD dwIndex;
    BOOL bFound = FALSE; 
    HANDLE hDev = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA pInterfaceDetailData = NULL;

    // set defaults
    *pdwRemovalPolicy = 0;
    pszDeviceInstanceId[0] = TEXT('\0');

    __try {
        hIntDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs (pGuidInferface, pszEnumerator, NULL,
                                           pGuidInferface != NULL? DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE:
                                                                   DIGCF_ALLCLASSES | DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
        if (hIntDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            __leave;

        for (dwIndex = 0; ;dwIndex ++) {
            SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA interfaceData;
            SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData;
            DWORD dwDataType, dwRequiredSize;
            BOOL bSuccess;

            ZeroMemory (&interfaceData, sizeof(interfaceData));
            interfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(interfaceData);
            bSuccess = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces (hIntDevInfo, NULL, pGuidInferface, dwIndex, &interfaceData);
            if (!bSuccess) {
                DWORD dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
                if (dwErrorCode == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
                    break;
                else 
                    break;  // ERROR!!!
            }

            dwRequiredSize = 0;
            bSuccess = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail (hIntDevInfo, &interfaceData, NULL, 0, &dwRequiredSize, NULL);
            if ((!bSuccess && GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) || dwRequiredSize == 0)
                continue;  // ERROR!!!

            if (pInterfaceDetailData)
                pInterfaceDetailData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) LocalFree (pInterfaceDetailData);

            pInterfaceDetailData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) LocalAlloc (LPTR, dwRequiredSize);
            pInterfaceDetailData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);
            ZeroMemory (&deviceInfoData, sizeof(deviceInfoData));
            deviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInfoData);
            bSuccess = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail (hIntDevInfo, &interfaceData,
                                                        pInterfaceDetailData, dwRequiredSize, &dwRequiredSize, &deviceInfoData);
            if (!bSuccess)
                continue;

            hDev = CreateFile (pInterfaceDetailData->DevicePath, 
                               0,                                   // no access to the drive
                               FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,  // share mode
                               NULL,                                // default security attributes
                               OPEN_EXISTING,                       // disposition
                               0,                                   // file attributes
                               NULL);                               // do not copy file attributes
            if (hDev != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER sdn;
                DWORD cbBytesReturned;
                bSuccess = DeviceIoControl (hDev,                           // device to be queried
                                            IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER, 
                                            NULL, 0,                        // no input buffer
                                            (LPVOID)&sdn, sizeof(sdn),      // output buffer
                                            &cbBytesReturned,               // # bytes returned
                                            (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL);           // synchronous I/O
                if (bSuccess) {
                    if (sdn.DeviceType == DeviceType &&
                        sdn.DeviceNumber == DeviceNumber) {

                        DEVINST dnDevInstParent, dnDevInstParentParent;
                        CONFIGRET ret;
                        // device found !!!
                        TCHAR szBuffer[4096];

                        _tprintf (TEXT("    DevicePath: %s\n"), pInterfaceDetailData->DevicePath);

                        bSuccess = SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId (hIntDevInfo, &deviceInfoData, pszDeviceInstanceId,
                                                               dwDeviceInstanceIdSize, &dwRequiredSize);
                        if (dwRequiredSize > MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN)
                            continue;

                        bSuccess = SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty (hIntDevInfo, &deviceInfoData, SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY, &dwDataType,
                                                                     (PBYTE)pdwRemovalPolicy, sizeof(DWORD), &dwRequiredSize);
                        // SPDRP_CHARACTERISTICS - Device characteristics
                        //         FILE_FLOPPY_DISKETTE, FILE_REMOVABLE_MEDIA, and FILE_WRITE_ONCE_MEDIA characteristics 
                        //         FILE_READ_ONLY_DEVICE
                        bSuccess = SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty (hIntDevInfo, &deviceInfoData, SPDRP_CLASS, &dwDataType,
                                                                     (PBYTE)szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), &dwRequiredSize);
                        if (bSuccess)
                            _tprintf (TEXT("    Class: \"%s\"\n"), szBuffer);
                        bSuccess = SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty (hIntDevInfo, &deviceInfoData, SPDRP_HARDWAREID, &dwDataType,
                                                                     (PBYTE)szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), &dwRequiredSize);
                        if (bSuccess) {
                            LPCTSTR pszId;
                            _tprintf (TEXT("    Hardware IDs:\n"));
                            for (pszId=szBuffer;
                                 *pszId != TEXT('\0') && pszId + dwRequiredSize/sizeof(TCHAR) <= szBuffer + ARRAYSIZE(szBuffer);
                                 pszId += lstrlen(pszId)+1) {

                                _tprintf (TEXT("        \"%s\"\n"), pszId);
                            }
                        }
                        bSuccess = SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty (hIntDevInfo, &deviceInfoData, SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME, &dwDataType,
                                                                     (PBYTE)szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), &dwRequiredSize);
                        if (bSuccess)
                            _tprintf (TEXT("    Friendly Name: \"%s\"\n"), szBuffer);

                        bSuccess = SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty (hIntDevInfo, &deviceInfoData, SPDRP_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_OBJECT_NAME, &dwDataType,
                                                                     (PBYTE)szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), &dwRequiredSize);
                        if (bSuccess)
                            _tprintf (TEXT("    Physical Device Object Name: \"%s\"\n"), szBuffer);

                        bSuccess = SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty (hIntDevInfo, &deviceInfoData, SPDRP_DEVICEDESC, &dwDataType,
                                                                     (PBYTE)szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), &dwRequiredSize);
                        if (bSuccess)
                            _tprintf (TEXT("    Device Description: \"%s\"\n"), szBuffer);
                        bFound = TRUE;

                        ret = CM_Get_Parent (&dnDevInstParent, deviceInfoData.DevInst, 0);
                        if (ret == CR_SUCCESS) {
                            TCHAR szDeviceInstanceID[MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN];
                            ret = CM_Get_Device_ID (dnDevInstParent, szDeviceInstanceID, ARRAY_SIZE(szDeviceInstanceID), 0);
                            if (ret == CR_SUCCESS) {
                                _tprintf (TEXT("    Parent Device Instance ID: %s\n"), szDeviceInstanceID);
                                DumpVidPidMi (szDeviceInstanceID);
                                ret = CM_Get_Parent (&dnDevInstParentParent, dnDevInstParent, 0);
                                if (ret == CR_SUCCESS) {
                                    ret = CM_Get_Device_ID (dnDevInstParentParent, szDeviceInstanceID, ARRAY_SIZE(szDeviceInstanceID), 0);
                                    if (ret == CR_SUCCESS)
                                        _tprintf (TEXT("    Parent of Parent Device Instance ID: %s\n"), szDeviceInstanceID);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

                CloseHandle (hDev);
                hDev = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
            }
        }
    }
    __finally {
        if (pInterfaceDetailData)
            pInterfaceDetailData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) LocalFree (pInterfaceDetailData);

        if (hDev != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            CloseHandle (hDev);

        if (hIntDevInfo)
            SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList (hIntDevInfo);
    }

    return bFound;
}

LPCTSTR DumpBusTypeAsString (STORAGE_BUS_TYPE type)
{
    const static LPCTSTR arStorageBusTypeNames[] = {
        TEXT("Unknown"),                    // BusTypeUnknown = 0
        TEXT("SCSI"),                       // BusTypeScsi = 1
        TEXT("ATAPI"),                      // BusTypeAtapi = 2
        TEXT("ATA"),                        // BusTypeAta = 3
        TEXT("IEEE-1394"),                  // BusType1394 = 4
        TEXT("SSA"),                        // BusTypeSsa = 5
        TEXT("Fibre Channel"),              // BusTypeFibre = 6
        TEXT("USB"),                        // BusTypeUsb = 7
        TEXT("RAID"),                       // BusTypeRAID = 8
        TEXT("iSCSI"),                      // BusTypeiScsi = 9
        TEXT("Serial Attached SCSI (SAS)"), // BusTypeSas = 10
        TEXT("SATA"),                       // BusTypeSata = 11
        TEXT("SD"),                         // BusTypeSd = 12
        TEXT("MMC"),                        // BusTypeMmc = 13
        TEXT("Virtual"),                    // BusTypeVirtual = 14
        TEXT("FileBackedVirtual")           // BusTypeFileBackedVirtual = 15
    };

    if (type <= BusTypeFileBackedVirtual)
        return arStorageBusTypeNames[type];
    else
        return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hDevice; 
    DWORD cbBytesReturned;
    STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER sdn;
    BOOL bSuccess;
    LPTSTR pszLogicalDrives, pszDriveRoot;
    TCHAR szDeviceInstanceId[MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN];
    GUID *pGuidInferface = NULL, *pGuidClass = NULL;
    LPCTSTR pszEnumerator = NULL;
    TCHAR szVolumeName[MAX_PATH+1], szFileSystemName[MAX_PATH+1], szNtDeviceName[MAX_PATH+1];
    //TCHAR szVolumeSerialNumber[1024];
    DWORD dwVolumeSerialNumber, dwMaximumComponentLength, dwFileSystemFlags;
    //HMODULE hm = LoadLibrary (TEXT("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\OUTLOOK.EXE"));

    __try {
        //pszEnumerator = TEXT("USB");

        cbBytesReturned = GetLogicalDriveStrings (0, NULL);
        pszLogicalDrives = (LPTSTR) LocalAlloc (LMEM_ZEROINIT,
                                                cbBytesReturned*sizeof(TCHAR));
        cbBytesReturned = GetLogicalDriveStrings (cbBytesReturned,
                                                  pszLogicalDrives);
        for (pszDriveRoot = pszLogicalDrives; *pszDriveRoot != TEXT('\0');
             pszDriveRoot += lstrlen(pszDriveRoot) + 1) {

            TCHAR szDeviceName[7] = TEXT("\\\\.\\");
            BOOL bIsRemoveable = FALSE;
            DWORD dwRemovalPolicy;
            STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY spq;
            BYTE byBuffer[4096];
            //ULONG ulOutBuffer;

            szDeviceName[4] = pszDriveRoot[0];
            szDeviceName[5] = TEXT(':');
            szDeviceName[6] = TEXT('\0');
            _tprintf (TEXT("Drive %c:\n"), pszDriveRoot[0]);

            // see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc542456.aspx
            // how to find Volume name: \\?\Volume{4c1b02c1-d990-11dc-99ae-806e6f6e6963}\
            // for the Paths:  C:\
            // or device name like \Device\HarddiskVolume2 or \Device\CdRom0
            cbBytesReturned = QueryDosDevice (&szDeviceName[4], szNtDeviceName, ARRAYSIZE(szNtDeviceName));
            if (cbBytesReturned) {
                _tprintf (TEXT("    Dos Device Name: %s\n"), szNtDeviceName);
                FildVolumeName(szNtDeviceName);
            }

            bSuccess = GetVolumeInformation (pszDriveRoot, szVolumeName, ARRAYSIZE(szVolumeName),
                &dwVolumeSerialNumber, &dwMaximumComponentLength, &dwFileSystemFlags,
                szFileSystemName, ARRAYSIZE(szFileSystemName));
            if (bSuccess) {
                _tprintf (TEXT("    Volume Name: \"%s\"\n"), szVolumeName);
            }

            hDevice = CreateFile (szDeviceName,
                                  //FILE_READ_DATA, //0 - no access to the drive, for IOCTL_STORAGE_CHECK_VERIFY is FILE_READ_DATA needed
                                  FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, // for IOCTL_STORAGE_CHECK_VERIFY2
                                  FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,   // share mode
                                  NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
            if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                __leave;

            bIsRemoveable = FALSE;

            spq.PropertyId = StorageDeviceProperty;
            spq.QueryType = PropertyStandardQuery;
            spq.AdditionalParameters[0] = 0;
            bSuccess = DeviceIoControl (hDevice,                         // device to be queried
                                        IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,    // operation to perform
                                        &spq, sizeof(spq),               // input buffer
                                        &byBuffer, sizeof(byBuffer),     // output buffer
                                        &cbBytesReturned,                // # bytes returned
                                        (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL);            // synchronous I/O
            if (bSuccess) {
                STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR *psdp = (STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR *)byBuffer;
                LPCTSTR pszBusType = DumpBusTypeAsString(psdp->BusType);
                if (pszBusType)
                    _tprintf (TEXT("    Bus Type: %s\n"), pszBusType);
                else
                    _tprintf (TEXT("    Bus Type: Unknown (%d)\n"), psdp->BusType);
                if (psdp->VendorIdOffset)
                    _tprintf (TEXT("    VendorId: \"%hs\"\n"), (LPCSTR)((PBYTE)psdp + psdp->VendorIdOffset));
                if (psdp->ProductIdOffset)
                    _tprintf (TEXT("    ProductId: \"%hs\"\n"), (LPCSTR)((PBYTE)psdp + psdp->ProductIdOffset));
                if (psdp->ProductRevisionOffset)
                    _tprintf (TEXT("    ProductRevision: \"%hs\"\n"), (LPCSTR)((PBYTE)psdp + psdp->ProductRevisionOffset));

                if (psdp->RemovableMedia)
                    bIsRemoveable = TRUE;
            }

            cbBytesReturned = 0;
            bSuccess = DeviceIoControl (hDevice,                     // device to be queried
                                        IOCTL_STORAGE_CHECK_VERIFY2,
                                        NULL, 0,                     // no input buffer
                                        NULL, 0,                     // no output buffer
                                        &cbBytesReturned,            // # bytes returned
                                        (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL);        // synchronous I/O
            if (bSuccess)
                _tprintf (TEXT("    the device media are accessible\n"));
            else if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_READY)
                _tprintf (TEXT("    the device media are not accessible\n"));

            bSuccess = DeviceIoControl (hDevice,                         // device to be queried
                                        IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER, 
                                        NULL, 0,                         // no input buffer
                                        (LPVOID)&sdn, sizeof(sdn),       // output buffer
                                        &cbBytesReturned,                // # bytes returned
                                        (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL);            // synchronous I/O
            // GetLastError of ERROR_MORE_DATA indicates to the caller that the buffer was not large enough to accommodate the data requested
            if (!bSuccess) __leave;
            _tprintf (TEXT("    DeviceType: %d, DeviceNumber: %d, PartitionNumber: %d\n"), sdn.DeviceType, sdn.DeviceNumber, sdn.PartitionNumber);

            pGuidInferface = NULL;
            pGuidClass = NULL;
            if (sdn.DeviceType == FILE_DEVICE_CD_ROM || sdn.DeviceType == FILE_DEVICE_DVD) {
                pGuidInferface = (GUID*)&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_CDROM;
                pGuidClass = (GUID*)&GUID_DEVCLASS_CDROM;
            }
            else if (sdn.DeviceType == FILE_DEVICE_DISK) {
                DEVICE_TYPE DeviceType;
                ULONG ulCharacteristics;
                bSuccess = GetDriveTypeAndCharacteristics (hDevice, &DeviceType, &ulCharacteristics);
                if (bSuccess) {
                    if ((ulCharacteristics & FILE_FLOPPY_DISKETTE) == FILE_FLOPPY_DISKETTE) {
                        pGuidInferface = (GUID*)&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_FLOPPY;
                        pGuidClass = (GUID*)&GUID_DEVCLASS_FLOPPYDISK;
                    }
                    else {
                        pGuidInferface = (GUID*)&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK;
                        pGuidClass = (GUID*)&GUID_DEVCLASS_DISKDRIVE;
                    }

                    if ((ulCharacteristics & FILE_REMOVABLE_MEDIA) == FILE_REMOVABLE_MEDIA)
                        bIsRemoveable = TRUE;
                }
            }
            // GUID_DEVCLASS_MEDIUM_CHANGER

            if (CloseHandle (hDevice))
                hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

            bSuccess = FindDiInfos (pGuidInferface, pGuidClass, pszEnumerator, sdn.DeviceType, sdn.DeviceNumber,
                                    ARRAY_SIZE(szDeviceInstanceId),     // MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN
                                    szDeviceInstanceId,
                                    &dwRemovalPolicy);
            if (bSuccess) {
                if (dwRemovalPolicy == CM_REMOVAL_POLICY_EXPECT_SURPRISE_REMOVAL ||
                    dwRemovalPolicy == CM_REMOVAL_POLICY_EXPECT_ORDERLY_REMOVAL)
                    bIsRemoveable = TRUE;
                _tprintf (TEXT("    DeviceInstanceId: %s\n"), szDeviceInstanceId);
                if (bIsRemoveable)
                    _tprintf (TEXT("    Drive %c: is removeable\n"), pszDriveRoot[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    __finally {
        if (pszLogicalDrives)
            pszLogicalDrives = (LPTSTR) LocalFree (pszLogicalDrives);
        if (hDevice != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            bSuccess = CloseHandle (hDevice);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program can be compiled without Windows DDK installed (only Windows SDK, which installed for example together with Visual Studio is required). The program produces output like following:

```
....
Drive L:
    Dos Device Name: \Device\CdRom2
    Volume Device Name: \\?\Volume{2c5f6a93-2b50-11df-aa6a-005056c00008}\
    Volume Name: "SONYPICTUTIL"
    Bus Type: USB
    VendorId: "HL-DT-ST"
    ProductId: "DVDRAM GE20LU11 "
    ProductRevision: "CL01"
    the device media are accessible
    DeviceType: 2, DeviceNumber: 2, PartitionNumber: -1
    DevicePath: \\?\usbstor#cdrom&ven_hl-dt-st&prod_dvdram_ge20lu11&rev_cl01#0010101640008b615&0#{53f56308-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
    Class: "CDROM"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USBSTOR\CdRomHL-DT-STDVDRAM_GE20LU11_CL01"
        "USBSTOR\CdRomHL-DT-STDVDRAM_GE20LU11_"
        "USBSTOR\CdRomHL-DT-ST"
        "USBSTOR\HL-DT-STDVDRAM_GE20LU11_C"
        "HL-DT-STDVDRAM_GE20LU11_C"
        "USBSTOR\GenCdRom"
        "GenCdRom"
    Friendly Name: "HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GE20LU11 USB Device"
    Physical Device Object Name: "\Device\00000096"
    Device Description: "CD-ROM Drive"
    Parent Device Instance ID: USB\VID_152E&PID_1640\0010101640008B615
        vid: "152E"
        pid: "1640"
    Parent of Parent Device Instance ID: USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&29A1BD9B&0
    DeviceInstanceId: USBSTOR\CDROM&VEN_HL-DT-ST&PROD_DVDRAM_GE20LU11&REV_CL01\0010101640008B615&0
    Drive L: is removeable
Drive N:
    Dos Device Name: \Device\HarddiskVolume8
    Volume Device Name: \\?\Volume{ae08a3c8-71cf-11de-bc1d-005056c00008}\
    Volume Name: ""
    Bus Type: USB
    VendorId: "SanDisk "
    ProductId: "Cruzer          "
    ProductRevision: "8.01"
    the device media are accessible
    DeviceType: 7, DeviceNumber: 5, PartitionNumber: 1
    DevicePath: \\?\usbstor#disk&ven_sandisk&prod_cruzer&rev_8.01#1740030578903736&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
    Class: "DiskDrive"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USBSTOR\DiskSanDisk_Cruzer__________8.01"
        "USBSTOR\DiskSanDisk_Cruzer__________"
        "USBSTOR\DiskSanDisk_"
        "USBSTOR\SanDisk_Cruzer__________8"
        "SanDisk_Cruzer__________8"
        "USBSTOR\GenDisk"
        "GenDisk"
    Friendly Name: "SanDisk Cruzer USB Device"
    Physical Device Object Name: "\Device\000000aa"
    Device Description: "Disk drive"
    Parent Device Instance ID: USB\VID_0781&PID_5406\1740030578903736
        vid: "0781"
        pid: "5406"
    Parent of Parent Device Instance ID: USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&128079C2&0
    DeviceInstanceId: USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_SANDISK&PROD_CRUZER&REV_8.01\1740030578903736&0
    Drive N: is removeable
```

Because we are interesting for only devices which are accessible through drive letters the program start with enumerating of all logical drives in the system with respect of `GetLogicalDriveStrings` function. For every drive we can use `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY` to get information like `VendorId`, `ProductId` and `ProductRevision`. The usage of `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER` allow us to get the drive type (like CD/DVD or Disk/Floppy).  Moreover two numbers: `DeviceType` and `DeviceNumber` are unique in the system and we can use these as the basis to fine the device instance (using `SetupDi`- functions) for the drive.

Because Floppy and Disk devices has the same defice type `FILE_DEVICE_DISK` I demonstrate another function `NtQueryVolumeInformationFile` with `FileFsDeviceInformation` parameter to get so named **Characteristics** for the device. The characteristic is the best way to destinguisch floppy from other disks and choose the corresponding class and interface GUID for the device enumeration (`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_FLOPPY` or `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK`). We get the DeviceType and DeviceNumber for all devices enumerated with respect of `SetupDi` API. In the way we find out which device has which drive letter.

One more important thing is the hierarchy of devices: parent/child relationship. To demonstrate this I use `CM_Get_Parent` and `CM_Get_Device_ID` functions in the code example. So we can see which USB device has which storage divice as the child.

I displayed some information about the found devices. You can combine API from the example with `IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS` (see [Using IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012828/using-ioctl-mountmgr-query-points)) or `FindFirstVolumeW`, `FindNextVolumeW` and `GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeNameW` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc542456(VS.85).aspx) to receive more detailed information if needed.

**UPDATED**: By the way the buffer returned by `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY` has another fields like `STORAGE_BUS_TYPE BusType` (`BusTypeUsb`, `BusTypeFibre`, `BusTypeSd` etc.) etc. You can also use `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY` to ask another information like `StorageDeviceUniqueIdProperty` or `StorageDeviceUniqueIdProperty` etc. If you want to have more USB specific information, I recommend you http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/USB_SerialNumbers.htm which shows the usage of `IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX`, `IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_INFORMATION` and `IOCTL_USB_GET_DESCRIPTOR_FROM_NODE_CONNECTION`.

**UPDATED 2:** I placed the extended version of program under http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/EnumMassStorage.c because of restriction with the message size in stackoverflow.com. The test output looks like folowing http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/EnumMassStorage.txt

**UPDATED 3:** I found a bug and updated the code. Please use the latest version of the code and verify that your problem is solved.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. What structures you mean? By the way look at the extended version of the code and the test output (see UPDATED 2 part of my answer)

Comment: This code is tested on Windows 7 32-bit and on Windows 7 64-bit also. Which kind of error you receive? Which versio of Visual Studio you use?

Comment: Could you explain what part of information is wrong? Do you have not all drives connected through USB? By the way I recommend you also use the version http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/EnumMassStorage.c which display more detailed information.

Comment: Kindly look at the above post...
i have pasted both the results of the systems (XP and windows 7 ) in the above post ...
i run same code but i get difffrent outputs..for same device...

Comment: Try with the fixed version. I hope now the program will work correct.

Comment: On both places there are new code: the code in my answer and on http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/EnumMassStorage.c

Comment: Are you found the new code? Is it works correct in your environment now?

Comment: i get 'BusTypeFileBackedVirtual' : undeclared identifier error when i run the code...

Comment: Then you use old windows headers (headers not for Windows 7). Two lines before you can see in the comment that `BusTypeFileBackedVirtual = 15`, so You can just define `BusTypeFileBackedVirtual` with th corresponding value or replace it with the value 15.

Comment: One should use `deviceInfoData` returned by `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail` instead of usage a separate `SetupDiGetClassDevs` (the last output parameter of the `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail`). You should better use WinDiff.exe (tool from Windows SDK or Visual Studio) to compare old version and the fixed one. Is the code works OK now in your environment?

Comment: I am glad to hear this. After all (after the problem will be soleved) could you change the title and the contain of your question to make able other people better find the solution. My current answer not quite corresponds to your question.

Comment: This code doesn't work if the volume is a mirror or other RAID array in Disk Management.  Example: I set up VirtualBox with two identical virtual hard drives.  Then I installed Windows 7 on the first drive.  After installing Windows 7, I went to Disk Management, converted to dynamic disks, and then mirrored the system partition to the second drive.  The result is not pretty: the code posted at Oleg's web site only makes it to printing the "Volume Name" and no farther.  The subsequent CreateFile or IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY must be failing...

Comment: Logically it makes sense - the volume spans multiple disks, so how to get information about each disk that makes up the volume?  The posted code doesn't show...  (BTW I'm not referring to RAID provided by system BIOS, but rather to the RAID features in Windows).