# msdn CM_GET_Parent Example Doesn't Work

Tags: winapi, windows-7, msdn

I am working on getting the device id from the usb device i plug...

The above application works on win-Xp but not in Windows 7

When i try to figure it i found that CM_Get_Parent () not works...

can anybody please guide me on why its not working ...and is there any compatible function which can work on windows 7

source code:

```
HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
GUID guid;
BYTE buffer[ 1024 ];
DWORD dwRequiredSize ;
WCHAR buf[ 1024 ];
DEVINST devInstParent;
WCHAR volume[1024];
int aLength, anIndex;
SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA devInterfaceData;
SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData;
PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA pDevDetail;

guid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME;
hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs( &guid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT );

if( hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
{
    qDebug() << "Error - SetupDiGetClassDevs failed\n";
}

for( DWORD dwIndex = 0;; dwIndex ++ )
{
    ZeroMemory( &devInterfaceData, sizeof( devInterfaceData ) );
    devInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(devInterfaceData );
    if( !SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, NULL, &guid,dwIndex, &devInterfaceData ) )
    {
        break;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &devInfoData, sizeof( devInfoData ) );
    devInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(devInfoData);

    pDevDetail = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)buffer;
    pDevDetail->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA );

    // Get device interface detail data to get Device Instance from
    // SP_DEVINFO_DATA and Device Path from SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA   
    SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
      hDevInfo,&devInterfaceData,
      pDevDetail, // SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
      1024,&dwRequiredSize,&devInfoData ); // SP_DEVINFO_DATA

    CM_Get_Parent( &devInstParent,devInfoData.DevInst, 0 );
    CM_Get_Parent( &devInstParent,devInstParent, 0 );
    CM_Get_Device_ID(  devInstParent, buf, 1024,0 );
}
```

Comment: Some time ago I posted you a code example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098696/how-to-get-the-vid-pid-and-drive-letter-for-all-the-usb-mass-storage-devices-plug which use `CM_Get_Parent` and which I tested under Windows 7. So if you have an example where `CM_Get_Parent ()` function not works you should post the corresponding code example which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following a litle modified code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <cfgmgr32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr)     (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))

#pragma comment (lib, "setupapi.lib")

int main()
{
    HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
    GUID guid;
    BYTE buffer[ 1024 ];
    DWORD dwRequiredSize ;
    DEVINST devInstParent;
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA devInterfaceData;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData;
    PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA pDevDetail;
    CONFIGRET status;
    TCHAR szDeviceInstanceID [MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN];
    BOOL bSuccess;

    guid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME;
    hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs( &guid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT );
    if( hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
        return 1;
    }

    for( DWORD dwIndex = 0;; dwIndex ++ ) {
        ZeroMemory( &devInterfaceData, sizeof( devInterfaceData ));
        devInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof( devInterfaceData );

        if( !SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces( hDevInfo, NULL, &guid, dwIndex, &devInterfaceData ) ) {
            DWORD dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
            if (dwErrorCode == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
                break;
            else 
                return 1;  // ERROR!!!
        }

        ZeroMemory( &devInfoData, sizeof( devInfoData ) );
        devInfoData.cbSize = sizeof( devInfoData);
        pDevDetail = ( PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA )buffer;
        pDevDetail->cbSize = sizeof( SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA );

        // Get device interface detail data to get Device Instance from
        // SP_DEVINFO_DATA and Device Path from SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
        bSuccess = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail( hDevInfo,&devInterfaceData,
               pDevDetail,// SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
               sizeof(buffer),&dwRequiredSize,&devInfoData ); // SP_DEVINFO_DATA
        status = CM_Get_Device_ID (devInfoData.DevInst, szDeviceInstanceID, ARRAY_SIZE(szDeviceInstanceID), 0);
        if (status == CR_SUCCESS) {
            _tprintf (TEXT("%s\n"), szDeviceInstanceID);
        }

        status = CM_Get_Parent( &devInstParent,devInfoData.DevInst, 0 );
        if (status == CR_SUCCESS) {
            status = CM_Get_Device_ID (devInstParent, szDeviceInstanceID, ARRAY_SIZE(szDeviceInstanceID), 0);
            if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
                _tprintf (TEXT("    %s\n"), szDeviceInstanceID);

            status = CM_Get_Parent( &devInstParent,devInstParent, 0 );
            if (status == CR_SUCCESS) {
                status = CM_Get_Device_ID(  devInstParent, szDeviceInstanceID, ARRAY_SIZE(szDeviceInstanceID), 0);
                if (status == CR_SUCCESS) {
                    _tprintf (TEXT("        %s\n"), szDeviceInstanceID);
                }
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

work without any problem on my Windows 7 computer and produce output like following:

```
SCSI\CDROM&VEN_ELBY&PROD_CLONEDRIVE&REV_1.4\1&2AFD7D61&0&000000
    ROOT\SCSIADAPTER\0000
        HTREE\ROOT\0
STORAGE\VOLUME\{21C004DA-0EB2-11DF-8C02-806E6F6E6963}#0000000000100000
    ROOT\VOLMGR\0000
        HTREE\ROOT\0
STORAGE\VOLUME\{21C004DA-0EB2-11DF-8C02-806E6F6E6963}#000000004B100000
    ROOT\VOLMGR\0000
        HTREE\ROOT\0
STORAGE\VOLUME\{21C004DA-0EB2-11DF-8C02-806E6F6E6963}#00000037C7A00000
    ROOT\VOLMGR\0000
        HTREE\ROOT\0
```

**UPDATED** based on the comment: On my Windows XP in the VMware the same utility produce the following output

```
FDC\GENERIC_FLOPPY_DRIVE\6&1435B2E2&0&0
    ACPI\PNP0700\5&324D5432&0
        ACPI\PNP0A05\4&5289E18&0
IDE\CDROMNECVMWAR_VMWARE_IDE_CDR10_______________1.00____\3031303030303030303030303030303030303130
    PCIIDE\IDECHANNEL\4&23686003&0&1
        PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_7111&SUBSYS_197615AD&REV_01\3&61AAA01&0&39
STORAGE\VOLUME\1&30A96598&0&SIGNATURE91929192OFFSET7E00LENGTH1FFD5AA00
    ROOT\FTDISK\0000
        HTREE\ROOT\0
```

Of cause it is another computer (a virtual computer) on the other operation system and we receive another list of devices. You current question was to make the function `CM_Get_Parent()` working on both Windows XP and Windows 7. The posted code do this like we can see. Or it is now work correctly on your Windows XP or Windows 7 computer?

How to get pid and vid (product id and ventor id) I described in [Get information about disk drives result on windows7 - 32 bit system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098696/how-to-get-the-vid-pid-and-drive-letter-for-all-the-usb-mass-storage-devices-plug/3100268#3100268), but for any **drive letters** and not for the **volume devices**. One can easy change the code to show more information like Volume name, Bus name and other information. But this all is already another question.

**UPDATED:** I placed the extended version of program from [Get information about disk drives result on windows7 - 32 bit system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098696/how-to-get-the-vid-pid-and-drive-letter-for-all-the-usb-mass-storage-devices-plug/3100268#3100268) under http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/EnumMassStorage.c because of restriction with the message size in stackoverflow.com. The test output looks like http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/EnumMassStorage.txt

Comment: @barbgal: Is the code run on your Windows 7 and Windows XP computers? Do you have still problems with `CM_Get_Parent()`?