# How to enumerate volumes on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, qt

I am not very proficient in Mac OS X programming, but I am working on a Qt application which needs info about the storage devices. Basically a list of hard drives and USB thumb drives.
The end result should be like a vector which contains the following info for each device:

string: Label
string: Mount point
string: Device description (aka friendly name)
uint64: Size
bool:   Is removable?

I've been doing it on Windows and the following post [Get information about disk drives result on windows7 - 32 bit system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098696/how-to-get-the-vid-pid-and-drive-letter-for-all-the-usb-mass-storage-devices-plug) have been of a great help. However, although I am very proficient in C/C++ I am not really good in Mac OS X programming, Cocoa and/or Objective-C, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should get you most of what you're looking for:

```
NSWorkspace   *ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSArray     *vols = [ws mountedLocalVolumePaths];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

for (NSString *path in vols) 
{
    NSDictionary* fsAttributes;
    NSString *description, *type, *name;
    BOOL removable, writable, unmountable, res;
    NSNumber *size;

    res = [ws getFileSystemInfoForPath:path 
                           isRemovable:&removable 
                            isWritable:&writable 
                         isUnmountable:&unmountable
                           description:&description
                                  type:&type];
    if (!res) continue;
    fsAttributes = [fm fileSystemAttributesAtPath:path];
    name         = [fm displayNameAtPath:path];
    size         = [fsAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSystemSize];

    NSLog(@"path=%@\nname=%@\nremovable=%d\nwritable=%d\nunmountable=%d\n"
           "description=%@\ntype=%@, size=%@\n\n",
          path, name, removable, writable, unmountable, description, type, size);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This does exactly what I need :)
I didn't find a way to display the information like the 'Friendly Name' on windows does, though I suppose there's a way to do it on a Mac (i thought it's the description field here, but it's a filesystem).
If you know how to retrieve that info, please let me know... otherwise, it's awesome :)

Comment: @emi: Hm, i don't know. I can't even find anything like this using the I/O Registry Explorer (located in `/Developer/Applications/Utilities`).

Comment: This used to be the correct answer, but is now deprecated. See this question for a current answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852056/is-fsgetvolumeinfo-the-recommended-alternative-to-nsworkspaces-deprecated-mount?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Well, back in the day we used [`FSGetVolumeInfo`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000107-CH1g-F13089). As for removability, that would be [`FSGetVolumeParms`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000107-CH1g-SW12) using `vMExtendedAttributes & 1<< bIsRemovable`. (Actually, I don't recall that particular API. There was something called Driver Gestalt, but it's gone now.)

I suppose there's a shiny Objective-C interface, but if nobody else replies, at least there's the C way.

Comment: The links to `FSGetVolumeInfo` and `FSGetVolumeParms` are now broken.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `getmntinfo()` (for an enumeration of mount points) and `statfs()` (for information about a *known* mount point.)