# Programmatically get hard drive info on macOS

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, macos, macos-carbon

I need a way to get complete hard drive info on OS X, meaning all hard drive model names, SATA/ATA controllers, volumes, disk identifiers, etc. I checked out `diskutil`, but it doesn't contain SATA controller info, `system_profiler` has all the information I need but its XML output is not necessarily organized as well as I'd like. Is there any low level Carbon/C API that would let me do this?

Comment: This thread might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545102

Comment: Maybe you should specify what you mean by "but its XML output is not necessarily organized as well as I'd like". If it's got all information you need then just use it: the output is a plist, so it should be perfectly easy to fetch everything you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get serial number from Mac hard disks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019244/how-to-get-serial-number-from-mac-hard-disks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [IOKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html). There's also this question on Stack Overflow: [How to get serial number from Mac hard disks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019244/how-to-get-serial-number-from-mac-hard-disks)