# Is FSGetVolumeInfo the recommended alternative to NSWorkspace's deprecated mountedLocalVolumePaths method?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-services

I need to get a list of mounted local volumes on Mac OS X. Previously, the Cocoa class `NSWorkspace` had a [`mountedLocalVolumePaths` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/mountedLocalVolumePaths) for getting the array of mount points for such volumes. Since Lion, this is now deprecated, with no hint in the documentation about what we should use instead.

The only other Apple-specific API I have found which provides this information is the [`FSGetVolumeInfo` function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSGetVolumeInfo) from the CoreServices.framework. This enumerates the mounted volumes if you pass `kFSInvalidVolumeRefNum` for the *volume* parameter and 1..N for the *volumeIndex*. It returns the volume name (as a `HFSUniStr255`) via the *volumeName* output parameter and the mount point via the *rootDirectory* output parameter as a `FSRef`, which in turn can be converted to a URL using `CFURLCreateFromFSRef()`.

This seems a little convoluted and unnecessarily low-level.

There are also the BSD-level functions, `getfsstat()` and `getmntinfo()` which both emit an array of `statfs` structs. The API seems saner than the Core Services version.

Are there any higher-level replacements I should be using instead?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about replacing mountedLocalVolumePaths. It has been around since 10.0 and was only recently deprecated. It's probably not going anywhere for at least another couple of major OS releases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a much simpler replacement, in a much more logical place than the older methods: [NSFileManager's `mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:options:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys%3aoptions%3a).