# SetupDiGetDeviceProperty usage example

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, msdn

Can anybody provide me with an example of using [`SetupDiGetDeviceProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551963) ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The following code

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <devguid.h>    // for GUID_DEVCLASS_CDROM etc
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <cfgmgr32.h>   // for MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN, CM_Get_Parent and CM_Get_Device_ID
#define INITGUID
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//#include "c:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\api\devpkey.h"

// include DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc from WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\api\devpropdef.h
#ifdef DEFINE_DEVPROPKEY
#undef DEFINE_DEVPROPKEY
#endif
#ifdef INITGUID
#define DEFINE_DEVPROPKEY(name, l, w1, w2, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, pid) EXTERN_C const DEVPROPKEY DECLSPEC_SELECTANY name = { { l, w1, w2, { b1, b2,  b3,  b4,  b5,  b6,  b7,  b8 } }, pid }
#else
#define DEFINE_DEVPROPKEY(name, l, w1, w2, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, pid) EXTERN_C const DEVPROPKEY name
#endif // INITGUID

// include DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc from WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\api\devpkey.h
DEFINE_DEVPROPKEY(DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc,  0x540b947e, 0x8b40, 0x45bc, 0xa8, 0xa2, 0x6a, 0x0b, 0x89, 0x4c, 0xbd, 0xa2, 4);     // DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING
DEFINE_DEVPROPKEY(DEVPKEY_Device_ContainerId,            0x8c7ed206, 0x3f8a, 0x4827, 0xb3, 0xab, 0xae, 0x9e, 0x1f, 0xae, 0xfc, 0x6c, 2);     // DEVPROP_TYPE_GUID
DEFINE_DEVPROPKEY(DEVPKEY_Device_FriendlyName,           0xa45c254e, 0xdf1c, 0x4efd, 0x80, 0x20, 0x67, 0xd1, 0x46, 0xa8, 0x50, 0xe0, 14);    // DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING
DEFINE_DEVPROPKEY(DEVPKEY_DeviceDisplay_Category,        0x78c34fc8, 0x104a, 0x4aca, 0x9e, 0xa4, 0x52, 0x4d, 0x52, 0x99, 0x6e, 0x57, 0x5a);  // DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING_LIST
DEFINE_DEVPROPKEY(DEVPKEY_Device_LocationInfo,           0xa45c254e, 0xdf1c, 0x4efd, 0x80, 0x20, 0x67, 0xd1, 0x46, 0xa8, 0x50, 0xe0, 15);    // DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING
DEFINE_DEVPROPKEY(DEVPKEY_Device_Manufacturer,           0xa45c254e, 0xdf1c, 0x4efd, 0x80, 0x20, 0x67, 0xd1, 0x46, 0xa8, 0x50, 0xe0, 13);    // DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING
DEFINE_DEVPROPKEY(DEVPKEY_Device_SecuritySDS,            0xa45c254e, 0xdf1c, 0x4efd, 0x80, 0x20, 0x67, 0xd1, 0x46, 0xa8, 0x50, 0xe0, 26);    // DEVPROP_TYPE_SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_STRING

#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr)     (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))

#pragma comment (lib, "setupapi.lib")

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *FN_SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW)(
  __in       HDEVINFO DeviceInfoSet,
  __in       PSP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData,
  __in       const DEVPROPKEY *PropertyKey,
  __out      DEVPROPTYPE *PropertyType,
  __out_opt  PBYTE PropertyBuffer,
  __in       DWORD PropertyBufferSize,
  __out_opt  PDWORD RequiredSize,
  __in       DWORD Flags
);

// List all USB devices with some additional information
void ListDevices (CONST GUID *pClassGuid, LPCTSTR pszEnumerator)
{
    unsigned i, j;
    DWORD dwSize, dwPropertyRegDataType;
    DEVPROPTYPE ulPropertyType;
    CONFIGRET status;
    HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;
    const static LPCTSTR arPrefix[3] = {TEXT("VID_"), TEXT("PID_"), TEXT("MI_")};
    TCHAR szDeviceInstanceID [MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN];
    TCHAR szDesc[1024], szHardwareIDs[4096];
    WCHAR szBuffer[4096];
    LPTSTR pszToken, pszNextToken;
    TCHAR szVid[MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN], szPid[MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN], szMi[MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN];
    FN_SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW fn_SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW = (FN_SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW)
        GetProcAddress (GetModuleHandle (TEXT("Setupapi.dll")), "SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW");

    // List all connected USB devices
    hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs (pClassGuid, pszEnumerator, NULL,
                                    pClassGuid != NULL ? DIGCF_PRESENT: DIGCF_ALLCLASSES | DIGCF_PRESENT);
    if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return;

    // Find the ones that are driverless
    for (i = 0; ; i++)  {
        DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof (DeviceInfoData);
        if (!SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, i, &DeviceInfoData))
            break;

        status = CM_Get_Device_ID(DeviceInfoData.DevInst, szDeviceInstanceID , MAX_PATH, 0);
        if (status != CR_SUCCESS)
            continue;

        // Display device instance ID
        _tprintf (TEXT("%s\n"), szDeviceInstanceID );

        if (SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty (hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, SPDRP_DEVICEDESC,
                                              &dwPropertyRegDataType, (BYTE*)szDesc,
                                              sizeof(szDesc),   // The size, in bytes
                                              &dwSize))
            _tprintf (TEXT("    Device Description: \"%s\"\n"), szDesc);

        if (SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty (hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, SPDRP_HARDWAREID,
                                              &dwPropertyRegDataType, (BYTE*)szHardwareIDs,
                                              sizeof(szHardwareIDs),    // The size, in bytes
                                              &dwSize)) {
            LPCTSTR pszId;
            _tprintf (TEXT("    Hardware IDs:\n"));
            for (pszId=szHardwareIDs;
                 *pszId != TEXT('\0') && pszId + dwSize/sizeof(TCHAR) <= szHardwareIDs + ARRAYSIZE(szHardwareIDs);
                 pszId += lstrlen(pszId)+1) {

                _tprintf (TEXT("        \"%s\"\n"), pszId);
            }
        }

        // Retreive the device description as reported by the device itself
        // On Vista and earlier, we can use only SPDRP_DEVICEDESC
        // On Windows 7, the information we want ("Bus reported device description") is
        // accessed through DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc
        if (fn_SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW && fn_SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW (hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, &DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc,
                                                                          &ulPropertyType, (BYTE*)szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), &dwSize, 0)) {

            if (fn_SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW (hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, &DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc,
                                              &ulPropertyType, (BYTE*)szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), &dwSize, 0))
                _tprintf (TEXT("    Bus Reported Device Description: \"%ls\"\n"), szBuffer);
            if (fn_SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW (hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, &DEVPKEY_Device_Manufacturer,
                                              &ulPropertyType, (BYTE*)szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), &dwSize, 0)) {
                _tprintf (TEXT("    Device Manufacturer: \"%ls\"\n"), szBuffer);
            }
            if (fn_SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW (hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, &DEVPKEY_Device_FriendlyName,
                                              &ulPropertyType, (BYTE*)szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), &dwSize, 0)) {
                _tprintf (TEXT("    Device Friendly Name: \"%ls\"\n"), szBuffer);
            }
            if (fn_SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW (hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, &DEVPKEY_Device_LocationInfo,
                                              &ulPropertyType, (BYTE*)szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), &dwSize, 0)) {
                _tprintf (TEXT("    Device Location Info: \"%ls\"\n"), szBuffer);
            }
            if (fn_SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW (hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, &DEVPKEY_Device_SecuritySDS,
                                              &ulPropertyType, (BYTE*)szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), &dwSize, 0)) {
                // See Security Descriptor Definition Language on MSDN
                // (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379567(v=vs.85).aspx)
                _tprintf (TEXT("    Device Security Descriptor String: \"%ls\"\n"), szBuffer);
            }
            if (fn_SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW (hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, &DEVPKEY_Device_ContainerId,
                                              &ulPropertyType, (BYTE*)szDesc, sizeof(szDesc), &dwSize, 0)) {
                StringFromGUID2((REFGUID)szDesc, szBuffer, ARRAY_SIZE(szBuffer));
                _tprintf (TEXT("    ContainerId: \"%ls\"\n"), szBuffer);
            }
            if (fn_SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW (hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, &DEVPKEY_DeviceDisplay_Category,
                                              &ulPropertyType, (BYTE*)szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), &dwSize, 0))
                _tprintf (TEXT("    Device Display Category: \"%ls\"\n"), szBuffer);
        }

        pszToken = _tcstok_s (szDeviceInstanceID , TEXT("\\#&"), &pszNextToken);
        while(pszToken != NULL) {
            szVid[0] = TEXT('\0');
            szPid[0] = TEXT('\0');
            szMi[0] = TEXT('\0');
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (_tcsncmp(pszToken, arPrefix[j], lstrlen(arPrefix[j])) == 0) {
                    switch(j) {
                        case 0:
                            _tcscpy_s(szVid, ARRAY_SIZE(szVid), pszToken);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            _tcscpy_s(szPid, ARRAY_SIZE(szPid), pszToken);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            _tcscpy_s(szMi, ARRAY_SIZE(szMi), pszToken);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (szVid[0] != TEXT('\0'))
                _tprintf (TEXT("    vid: \"%s\"\n"), szVid);
            if (szPid[0] != TEXT('\0'))
                _tprintf (TEXT("    pid: \"%s\"\n"), szPid);
            if (szMi[0] != TEXT('\0'))
                _tprintf (TEXT("    mi: \"%s\"\n"), szMi);
            pszToken = _tcstok_s (NULL, TEXT("\\#&"), &pszNextToken);
        }
    }

    return;
}

int _tmain()
{
    // List all connected USB devices
    _tprintf (TEXT("---------------\n"));
    _tprintf (TEXT("- USB devices -\n"));
    _tprintf (TEXT("---------------\n"));
    ListDevices(NULL, TEXT("USB"));

    _tprintf (TEXT("\n"));
    _tprintf (TEXT("-------------------\n"));
    _tprintf (TEXT("- USBSTOR devices -\n"));
    _tprintf (TEXT("-------------------\n"));
    ListDevices(NULL, TEXT("USBSTOR"));

    _tprintf (TEXT("\n"));
    _tprintf (TEXT("--------------\n"));
    _tprintf (TEXT("- SD devices -\n"));
    _tprintf (TEXT("--------------\n"));
    ListDevices(NULL, TEXT("SD"));

    //_tprintf (TEXT("\n"));
    //ListDevices(&GUID_DEVCLASS_USB, NULL);
    //_tprintf (TEXT("\n"));

    _tprintf (TEXT("\n"));
    _tprintf (TEXT("-----------\n"));
    _tprintf (TEXT("- Volumes -\n"));
    _tprintf (TEXT("-----------\n"));
    //ListDevices(NULL, TEXT("STORAGE\\VOLUME"));
    //_tprintf (TEXT("\n"));
    ListDevices(&GUID_DEVCLASS_VOLUME, NULL);

    _tprintf (TEXT("\n"));
    _tprintf (TEXT("----------------------------\n"));
    _tprintf (TEXT("- devices with disk drives -\n"));
    _tprintf (TEXT("----------------------------\n"));
    ListDevices(&GUID_DEVCLASS_DISKDRIVE, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

produces the following output on my Windows 7 computer

```
---------------
- USB devices -
---------------
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&1C1548F&0
    Device Description: "USB Root Hub"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\ROOT_HUB20&VID8086&PID3B3C&REV0006"
        "USB\ROOT_HUB20&VID8086&PID3B3C"
        "USB\ROOT_HUB20"
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&2851D18A&0
    Device Description: "USB Root Hub"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\ROOT_HUB20&VID8086&PID3B34&REV0006"
        "USB\ROOT_HUB20&VID8086&PID3B34"
        "USB\ROOT_HUB20"
USB\VID_046D&PID_C52B\6&32FEB3AB&0&2
    Device Description: "USB Composite Device"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\VID_046D&PID_C52B&REV_1201"
        "USB\VID_046D&PID_C52B"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "USB Receiver"
    Device Manufacturer: "(Standard USB Host Controller)"
    Device Location Info: "Port_#0002.Hub_#0003"
    ContainerId: "{AB5F3BBF-21FC-11E2-9436-70F3954A2325}"
    vid: "VID_046D"
    pid: "PID_C52B"
USB\VID_046D&PID_C52B&MI_00\7&33519F3A&0&0000
    Device Description: "USB Input Device (Logitech Download Assistant)"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\VID_046D&PID_C52B&REV_1201&MI_00"
        "USB\VID_046D&PID_C52B&MI_00"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "USB Receiver"
    Device Manufacturer: "Logitech (x64)"
    Device Location Info: "0000.001a.0000.001.002.000.000.000.000"
    ContainerId: "{AB5F3BBF-21FC-11E2-9436-70F3954A2325}"
    vid: "VID_046D"
    pid: "PID_C52B"
    mi: "MI_00"
USB\VID_046D&PID_C52B&MI_01\7&33519F3A&0&0001
    Device Description: "USB Input Device"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\VID_046D&PID_C52B&REV_1201&MI_01"
        "USB\VID_046D&PID_C52B&MI_01"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "USB Receiver"
    Device Manufacturer: "(Standard system devices)"
    Device Location Info: "0000.001a.0000.001.002.000.000.000.000"
    ContainerId: "{AB5F3BBF-21FC-11E2-9436-70F3954A2325}"
    vid: "VID_046D"
    pid: "PID_C52B"
    mi: "MI_01"
USB\VID_046D&PID_C52B&MI_02\7&33519F3A&0&0002
    Device Description: "Logitech Unifying USB receiver"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\VID_046D&PID_C52B&REV_1201&MI_02"
        "USB\VID_046D&PID_C52B&MI_02"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "USB Receiver"
    Device Manufacturer: "Logitech"
    Device Location Info: "0000.001a.0000.001.002.000.000.000.000"
    ContainerId: "{AB5F3BBF-21FC-11E2-9436-70F3954A2325}"
    vid: "VID_046D"
    pid: "PID_C52B"
    mi: "MI_02"
USB\VID_05C6&PID_9205\6&7A6FBD7&0&4
    Device Description: "Qualcomm Gobi 2000 USB Composite Device 9205"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\VID_05C6&PID_9205&REV_0002"
        "USB\VID_05C6&PID_9205"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "Qualcomm Gobi 2000"
    Device Manufacturer: "Qualcomm Incorporated"
    Device Location Info: "Port_#0004.Hub_#0004"
    ContainerId: "{00000000-0000-0000-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF}"
    vid: "VID_05C6"
    pid: "PID_9205"
USB\VID_05C6&PID_9205&MI_00\7&210D4D2D&1&0000
    Device Description: "Qualcomm Gobi 2000 HS-USB Mobile Broadband Device 9205"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\VID_05C6&PID_9205&REV_0002&MI_00"
        "USB\VID_05C6&PID_9205&MI_00"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "Qualcomm Gobi 2000"
    Device Manufacturer: "Qualcomm Incorporated"
    Device Location Info: "0000.001d.0000.001.004.000.000.000.000"
    ContainerId: "{00000000-0000-0000-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF}"
    vid: "VID_05C6"
    pid: "PID_9205"
    mi: "MI_00"
USB\VID_05C6&PID_9205&MI_01\7&210D4D2D&1&0001
    Device Description: "Qualcomm Gobi 2000 HS-USB Diagnostics 9205"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\VID_05C6&PID_9205&REV_0002&MI_01"
        "USB\VID_05C6&PID_9205&MI_01"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "Qualcomm Gobi 2000"
    Device Manufacturer: "Qualcomm Incorporated"
    Device Friendly Name: "Qualcomm Gobi 2000 HS-USB Diagnostics 9205 (COM6)"
    Device Location Info: "0000.001d.0000.001.004.000.000.000.000"
    ContainerId: "{00000000-0000-0000-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF}"
    vid: "VID_05C6"
    pid: "PID_9205"
    mi: "MI_01"
USB\VID_05C6&PID_9205&MI_02\7&210D4D2D&1&0002
    Device Description: "Qualcomm Gobi 2000 HS-USB Modem 9205"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\VID_05C6&PID_9205&REV_0002&MI_02"
        "USB\VID_05C6&PID_9205&MI_02"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "Qualcomm Gobi 2000"
    Device Manufacturer: "Qualcomm Incorporated"
    Device Friendly Name: "Qualcomm Gobi 2000 HS-USB Modem 9205"
    Device Location Info: "0000.001d.0000.001.004.000.000.000.000"
    ContainerId: "{00000000-0000-0000-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF}"
    vid: "VID_05C6"
    pid: "PID_9205"
    mi: "MI_02"
USB\VID_05C6&PID_9205&MI_03\7&210D4D2D&1&0003
    Device Description: "Qualcomm Gobi 2000 HS-USB NMEA 9205"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\VID_05C6&PID_9205&REV_0002&MI_03"
        "USB\VID_05C6&PID_9205&MI_03"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "Qualcomm Gobi 2000"
    Device Manufacturer: "Qualcomm Incorporated"
    Device Friendly Name: "Qualcomm Gobi 2000 HS-USB NMEA 9205 (COM7)"
    Device Location Info: "0000.001d.0000.001.004.000.000.000.000"
    ContainerId: "{00000000-0000-0000-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF}"
    vid: "VID_05C6"
    pid: "PID_9205"
    mi: "MI_03"
USB\VID_0781&PID_7108\00000000000000031753
    Device Description: "USB Mass Storage Device"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\Vid_0781&Pid_7108&Rev_2000"
        "USB\Vid_0781&Pid_7108"
    vid: "VID_0781"
    pid: "PID_7108"
USB\VID_0930&PID_6545\00D0C9CCDF49EBC06000806C
    Device Description: "USB Mass Storage Device"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\Vid_0930&Pid_6545&Rev_0100"
        "USB\Vid_0930&Pid_6545"
    vid: "VID_0930"
    pid: "PID_6545"
USB\VID_0A5C&PID_217F\70F3954A2325
    Device Description: "ThinkPad Bluetooth 3.0"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\VID_0A5C&PID_217F&REV_0360"
        "USB\VID_0A5C&PID_217F"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "Broadcom Bluetooth Device"
    Device Manufacturer: "Broadcom"
    Device Location Info: "Port_#0004.Hub_#0003"
    ContainerId: "{00000000-0000-0000-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF}"
    vid: "VID_0A5C"
    pid: "PID_217F"
USB\VID_147E&PID_2016\6&32FEB3AB&0&3
    Device Description: "TouchChip Fingerprint Coprocessor (WBF advanced mode)"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\VID_147E&PID_2016&REV_0002"
        "USB\VID_147E&PID_2016"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "Biometric Coprocessor"
    Device Manufacturer: "AuthenTec"
    Device Location Info: "Port_#0003.Hub_#0003"
    Device Security Descriptor String: "D:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GA;;;SY)"
    ContainerId: "{00000000-0000-0000-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF}"
    vid: "VID_147E"
    pid: "PID_2016"
USB\VID_17EF&PID_480F\6&32FEB3AB&0&6
    Device Description: "USB Composite Device"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\VID_17EF&PID_480F&REV_2345"
        "USB\VID_17EF&PID_480F"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "Integrated Camera"
    Device Manufacturer: "(Standard USB Host Controller)"
    Device Location Info: "Port_#0006.Hub_#0003"
    ContainerId: "{00000000-0000-0000-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF}"
    vid: "VID_17EF"
    pid: "PID_480F"
USB\VID_17EF&PID_480F&MI_00\7&137E78B0&0&0000
    Device Description: "Integrated Camera"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\VID_17EF&PID_480F&REV_2345&MI_00"
        "USB\VID_17EF&PID_480F&MI_00"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "Integrated Camera"
    Device Manufacturer: "Ricoh"
    Device Friendly Name: "Integrated Camera"
    Device Location Info: "0000.001a.0000.001.006.000.000.000.000"
    ContainerId: "{00000000-0000-0000-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF}"
    Device Display Category: "Imaging.Webcam"
    vid: "VID_17EF"
    pid: "PID_480F"
    mi: "MI_00"
USB\VID_8087&PID_0020\5&15BBD570&0&1
    Device Description: "Generic USB Hub"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\VID_8087&PID_0020&REV_0000"
        "USB\VID_8087&PID_0020"
    vid: "VID_8087"
    pid: "PID_0020"
USB\VID_8087&PID_0020\5&29432BF7&0&1
    Device Description: "Generic USB Hub"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USB\VID_8087&PID_0020&REV_0000"
        "USB\VID_8087&PID_0020"
    vid: "VID_8087"
    pid: "PID_0020"

-------------------
- USBSTOR devices -
-------------------
USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_KINGSTON&PROD_DATATRAVELER_108&REV_PMAP\00D0C9CCDF49EBC06000806C&0
    Device Description: "Disk drive"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USBSTOR\DiskKingstonDataTraveler_108PMAP"
        "USBSTOR\DiskKingstonDataTraveler_108"
        "USBSTOR\DiskKingston"
        "USBSTOR\KingstonDataTraveler_108P"
        "KingstonDataTraveler_108P"
        "USBSTOR\GenDisk"
        "GenDisk"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "Kingston DataTraveler 108 USB Device"
    Device Manufacturer: "(Standard disk drives)"
    Device Friendly Name: "Kingston DataTraveler 108 USB Device"
    ContainerId: "{D9CC9C62-4C1D-5CC2-953C-9B0E27AB05E0}"
USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_SANDISK&PROD_CRUZER_TITANIUM&REV_2000\00000000000000031753&0
    Device Description: "Disk drive"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USBSTOR\DiskSanDisk_Cruzer_Titanium_2000"
        "USBSTOR\DiskSanDisk_Cruzer_Titanium_"
        "USBSTOR\DiskSanDisk_"
        "USBSTOR\SanDisk_Cruzer_Titanium_2"
        "SanDisk_Cruzer_Titanium_2"
        "USBSTOR\GenDisk"
        "GenDisk"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "SanDisk Cruzer Titanium USB Device"
    Device Manufacturer: "(Standard disk drives)"
    Device Friendly Name: "SanDisk Cruzer Titanium USB Device"
    ContainerId: "{DB834D8A-6F58-11E2-AA64-70F3954A2325}"

--------------
- SD devices -
--------------
SD\VID_74&OID_4A45&PID_USD&REV_1.0\5&3369D5EF&0&0
    Device Description: "SD Storage Card"
    Hardware IDs:
        "SD\VID_74&OID_4a45&PID_USD&REV_1.0"
        "SD\VID_74&OID_4a45&PID_USD"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "SD Memory Card"
    Device Manufacturer: "Generic"
    Device Friendly Name: "SD Memory Card"
    ContainerId: "{C17922A4-7814-11E2-BF78-70F3954A2325}"
    vid: "VID_74"
    pid: "PID_USD"

-----------
- Volumes -
-----------
STORAGE\VOLUME\_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_SANDISK&PROD_CRUZER_TITANIUM&REV_2000#00000000000000031753&0#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}
    Device Description: "Generic volume"
    Hardware IDs:
        "STORAGE\Volume"
STORAGE\VOLUME\{0A6B09D2-D440-11E1-9886-806E6F6E6963}#0000000000100000
    Device Description: "Generic volume"
    Hardware IDs:
        "STORAGE\Volume"
STORAGE\VOLUME\{0A6B09D2-D440-11E1-9886-806E6F6E6963}#0000000006500000
    Device Description: "Generic volume"
    Hardware IDs:
        "STORAGE\Volume"
STORAGE\VOLUME\_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_KINGSTON&PROD_DATATRAVELER_108&REV_PMAP#00D0C9CCDF49EBC06000806C&0#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}
    Device Description: "Generic volume"
    Hardware IDs:
        "STORAGE\Volume"
STORAGE\VOLUME\_??_SD#VID_74&OID_4A45&PID_USD&REV_1.0#5&3369D5EF&0&0#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}
    Device Description: "Generic volume"
    Hardware IDs:
        "STORAGE\Volume"
    vid: "VID_74"
    pid: "PID_USD"

----------------------------
- devices with disk drives -
----------------------------
IDE\DISKSAMSUNG_SSD_830_SERIES__________________CXM02B1Q\4&398487B7&0&0.0.0
    Device Description: "Disk drive"
    Hardware IDs:
        "IDE\DiskSAMSUNG_SSD_830_Series__________________CXM02B1Q"
        "IDE\SAMSUNG_SSD_830_Series__________________CXM02B1Q"
        "IDE\DiskSAMSUNG_SSD_830_Series__________________"
        "SAMSUNG_SSD_830_Series__________________CXM02B1Q"
        "GenDisk"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "SAMSUNG SSD 830 Series"
    Device Manufacturer: "(Standard disk drives)"
    Device Friendly Name: "SAMSUNG SSD 830 Series"
    Device Location Info: "0"
    ContainerId: "{00000000-0000-0000-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF}"
USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_KINGSTON&PROD_DATATRAVELER_108&REV_PMAP\00D0C9CCDF49EBC06000806C&0
    Device Description: "Disk drive"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USBSTOR\DiskKingstonDataTraveler_108PMAP"
        "USBSTOR\DiskKingstonDataTraveler_108"
        "USBSTOR\DiskKingston"
        "USBSTOR\KingstonDataTraveler_108P"
        "KingstonDataTraveler_108P"
        "USBSTOR\GenDisk"
        "GenDisk"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "Kingston DataTraveler 108 USB Device"
    Device Manufacturer: "(Standard disk drives)"
    Device Friendly Name: "Kingston DataTraveler 108 USB Device"
    ContainerId: "{D9CC9C62-4C1D-5CC2-953C-9B0E27AB05E0}"
SD\VID_74&OID_4A45&PID_USD&REV_1.0\5&3369D5EF&0&0
    Device Description: "SD Storage Card"
    Hardware IDs:
        "SD\VID_74&OID_4a45&PID_USD&REV_1.0"
        "SD\VID_74&OID_4a45&PID_USD"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "SD Memory Card"
    Device Manufacturer: "Generic"
    Device Friendly Name: "SD Memory Card"
    ContainerId: "{C17922A4-7814-11E2-BF78-70F3954A2325}"
    vid: "VID_74"
    pid: "PID_USD"
USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_SANDISK&PROD_CRUZER_TITANIUM&REV_2000\00000000000000031753&0
    Device Description: "Disk drive"
    Hardware IDs:
        "USBSTOR\DiskSanDisk_Cruzer_Titanium_2000"
        "USBSTOR\DiskSanDisk_Cruzer_Titanium_"
        "USBSTOR\DiskSanDisk_"
        "USBSTOR\SanDisk_Cruzer_Titanium_2"
        "SanDisk_Cruzer_Titanium_2"
        "USBSTOR\GenDisk"
        "GenDisk"
    Bus Reported Device Description: "SanDisk Cruzer Titanium USB Device"
    Device Manufacturer: "(Standard disk drives)"
    Device Friendly Name: "SanDisk Cruzer Titanium USB Device"
    ContainerId: "{DB834D8A-6F58-11E2-AA64-70F3954A2325}"
```

The lines with "Bus Reported Device Description" displays results of `SetupDiGetDeviceProperty` call. You can get some additional information about devices if you would follow another answers: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3100268/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3018530/315935).

Comment: `"SetupDiGetDevicePropertyA"` does not exist [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551963(v=vs.85).aspx), so if you want to see the output of "Bus Reported Device Description" when running NON-UNICODE, you need to put in this line: `printf ( ("    Bus Reported Device Description: \"%ls\"\n"), (WCHAR *)szDesc);` and change `SetupDiGetDevicePropertyA` to `SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW` towards the top.

Comment: @phyatt: Thank you for your comment. I didn't compiles to non-Unicode since many years. :-) In any way you are right and I updated the code which I posted 2,5 years before. At the end of the answer I included references to two other my old answers which can provide additional information about disk devices.

Comment: @PrakashBhagat: You are welcome! I'm glad that my old answer still helps.

Comment: thank you SO much! I was trying to find the location of the device of a WM_INPUT message, this answer showed me I can match its name to `szDeviceInstanceID` of a USB enumeration and find the location there.

Comment: Great! I was getting a compiler error (VS2015) `main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__StringFromGUID2@12 referenced in function "void __cdecl ListDevices(struct _GUID const *,wchar_t const *)" (?ListDevices@@YAXPBU_GUID@@PB_W@Z)` I fixed that by adding `Ole32.lib` to project @ Properties >> Linkier >> Input >> Additional dependencies.

Comment: @zadane: Thanks for the information! It could be helpful for other visitors. I'm still happy that the answer posted more as 5 years ago is still helpful.

Comment: I build it for Qt as well using Qt Creator, that's where I needed it with slight alteration by removing `_tprintf` functions and converting the WCHAR to unicode strings (only those necessary). I was thinking I might be worth posting that as additional answer for those who wants to use this code with Qt :)

Comment: Here's the documentation for SetupDiGetDeviceProperty(): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551963. Curiously, it mentions SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW() at the bottom, but not SetupDiGetDevicePropertyA(). Most functions in this group have both 'A' and 'W' variants. I also don't see SetupDiGetDevicePropertyA() in the header file, so I'm guessing it's not available.

Comment: @EdwardFalk: You can use `dumpbin.exe /exports %SystemRoot%\system32\SetupAPI.dll` tool, for example, to see the full list of functions exported from SetupAPI.dll. You will see that only `SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW` will be exported, but no `SetupDiGetDevicePropertyA`.

Comment: @Oleg Here's the proper way to include the DEVPKEY_* GUIDs: `#include <initguid.h>` followed by `#include <devpkey.h>`.

Comment: In case people re-use this code without exiting just after, `SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(&DeviceInfoData);` should be added.