# Find USB Mass Storage Instance Id based on Drive Letter in Window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, usb, usb-drive

I have a requirement in which I need to fetch USB Mass Storage Metadata [VID, PID and Serial No].

I found a nice post for enumerating USB devices and list out all the Mass storage Devices.

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438366/setupdigetdeviceproperty)

Now What I want is based on the drive letter, need to retrieve USB Mass Storage Metadata.

Thanks in advance for your kind support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had read and understood the "USB drive to drive letter" questions, this one would have been simple too. Enumerate both, compare, pick the match. Works in both directions.

Comment: I am on that way. But if you can post code it will help. Thanks in advance.