# How to retrieve 'bus reported device description' from arriving usb device

Tags: windows, qt, winapi, usb

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438366/setupdigetdeviceproperty) is the closest I could fine but it enumerates all usb devices. In my case I am handling `WM_DEVICECHANGE` event where I handle arriving usb device and want to gather extended information from this device when its plugged in other than the simple USB strings that contains the vid and pid.

I can't find any resource on it, is that possible?

I am using windows 7 and qt 5.5

Comment: This is not Qt-specific at all.

Comment: @KubaOber I am using Qt, I think it's applicable. Never know if qt has some functions for it.

Comment: Qt, at the moment, has no generally considered device management support.

Comment: @zadane, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438366/setupdigetdeviceproperty