# Drive letter from USB Device Path String

Tags: c++, windows

I have been searching for quite a while but not luck yet. Currently I am am able to retrieve the USB device path which looks like this

```
\?\usb#vid_046d&pid_0a44#7&12ebe04e&0&3#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}
```

However i need the drive letter for this USB device. i.e E:\

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995957/how-to-get-the-drive-letter-for-the-devicepath

Comment: This information is available from Windows Management Information (WMI). Once you have the `Win32_PnPEntity' for the device you can follow WMI associations: `Win32_PnPEntity' to 'Win32_DiskDrive' to `Win32_DiskPartition` to 'Win32_LogicalDisk'. The last of which has a `DeviceID` property giving the drive letter. WMI from C++ will mean using its COM API.