# USB Drive Letter

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am using Win32 API. What I have is SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA DevicePath. Using this device path I get VID and PID of the USB device

my device path looks like below

> "\?\usb#vid_04f2&pid_0111#5&39fe81e&0&2#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}"

Is there any way to get the drive letter to my device path?

Comment: The Windows API can be used from both C and C++ (and any other language that allows calling a C interface). The OP doesn't care, whether the answer is given in C or C++. Tagging it with both is usually fine.

Comment: There can be more than one USB function corresponding to a USB device.  Each USB mass storage function is a disk device, a disk device can contain multiple volumes (partitions).  A volume can have multiple mount points.  And a mount point is not necessarily a drive letter.  Do you want all the mount points which represent portions of that USB device, or exactly one?  And if exactly one, what's the rule for choosing between potentially multiple?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995957/how-to-get-the-drive-letter-for-the-devicepath

Comment: Which one do you want, drive letter or device path?