# Find which drive corresponds to which USB mass storage device in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, usb-mass-storage, usb

I have several USB mass storage flash drives connected to a Ubuntu Linux computer (Ubuntu 10.04.1, kernel 2.6.32-25-386), and I need to tell them apart programatically (from bash if possible, but I'm not afraid of compiling either) - I need to find which block device corresponds to which *physical* device (e.g. `/dev/sdb1` -> device in USB port 1; in my case, one device ~ one volume).

In other words, I know that I have three hardware devices plugged into USB ports; each of them shows up in the system as a USB mass storage device (as seen with lsusb), is created as a block device (`/dev/sdb1`) and automounted by UUID (`/media/1234-5678`).

```
USB device               block device    mountpoint
USB device in port 2.2 <-> /dev/sdb1   <-> /media/1234-5678
```

I'm *not* trying to find the relationship between block device and mountpoint; **I'm trying to find the relationship between block device and USB device, is there a way?**

Why? There will be some writes on the disks, with unpredictable time of completion. I need to give the operator some indication like "you can now remove the disk in port 2 (which is second from the left)". I have found which physical port corresponds to which port number on that specific machine, and finding block devices from mountpoints is simple; now I'm stuck mapping the logical USB ports to block devices.

I can see the disks with lsusb :

```
Bus 001 Device 058: ID 067b:2517 Prolific Technology, Inc. Mass Storage Device
Bus 001 Device 060: ID 067b:2517 Prolific Technology, Inc. Mass Storage Device
Bus 001 Device 061: ID 067b:2517 Prolific Technology, Inc. Mass Storage Device
```

and I can see them mounted (by their UUID):

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/BC88-15C4 type vfat
/dev/sdc1 on /media/AE54-65AA type vfat
/dev/sdd1 on /media/58D2-FED1 type vfat
```

Now, all the drives are the same model from the same manufacturer, so I can't distinguish them by that, and I can't guarantee they'll be plugged in a particular order.

I have found `/sys/bus/usb/devices` (a list of USB devices), but it seems to be the same data that I get from lsusb - I don't see a mapping to disks there.

There's also `/sys/block/sdb` and `/sys/block/sdb/sdb1` (the block device and its first partition; similarly for `sdc` and `sdd`), but again, I see no mapping to devices.

Comment: (tried the same thing in XP a while ago, abandoned the effort when requirements changed; the requirements changed back, but we've moved to Linux in the meantime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733206/find-which-drive-corresponds-to-which-usb-mass-storage-device-in-winxp )

Comment: Eyes I have, yet I don't see. Solved (/sys/block/sdX is a symlink to the USB device)!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure in which kernel version this was implemented, but the `/sys/block/*` entries are symlinks to the devices.

In other words, `/sys/block/sdb` symlinks to a different directory, and its name contains the USB device ID.

```
$ file /sys/block/sdb
/sys/block/sdb: symbolic link to `../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/host31/target31:0:0/31:0:0:0/block/sdb'
                                                  USB version and port here---^^^^^
```

The `1-1.1` is the interesting part, denoting `usb1-port 1.device 1`. When plugged into a hub, another level is added: `1-2.3.1`, denoting `usb1-port 2.port 3.device 1`.

Pseudocode:

```
get partition name # e.g. /dev/sdb1
get disk name # that would be /dev/sdb
get your basename # sdb
see where /sys/block/$your_basename points to # e.g. ../devices/blah/blah/1-2.1/blah
get the longest substring matching "\d-\d+(.\d+)*"  # e.g. 1-2.1
that is the device id you want
/sys/bus/usb/devices/$device_id/ has all kinds of information about it
the ID corresponds to hardware USB ports
```

[Working example script in bash](http://so.piskvor.org/3881449/).

Answer (score 1):

I use the path:

```
/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage/4-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sda
```

so you can see usb bus 4, port 1 is connected with a usb storage /dev/sda

Answer (score -1):

Can't you use disk labels?
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=322973

Comment: Thank you, but I've already solved that step. I can map from a mountpoint to a block device - I'm looking for a way to map the block device to the USB device and therefore to the hardware device. Edited answer to clarify.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I do it.

`lsusb -v` shows all the devices disks get an iserial number take note of them

```
 ls -l /dev/disk | grep [iserial]
```

Everything in `/dev/disk` is a symlink so follow the symlink to see the device.

Comment: Can't get that to work, sorry: `ls -l /dev/disk`, in my case, contains the directories `by-id  by-label  by-path  by-uuid`; `lsusb -v` gives me results like `iSerial 3`, and I seem to be unable to match that by any of the symlinks in the above directories. Moreover, the serials reported in `/dev/disk/by-id` seem to be valid for SATA disks, but bogus for the USB devices I have at hand: `usb-Generic_USB_12345678901234567890-0:0 -> ../../sde` (literally, the sequence 1-0 repeated twice). Kubuntu 12.04, kernel 3.2.0-32