# How to find the filesystem path to a USB-connected device?

Tags: windows, vb6, filesystems, usb, smartphone

I want to copy files from the phone to the hard disk (by Visual basic 6.0). The phone is connected as a USB device.

I don't know what is the path of the phone ... It is not a letter like the hard disk (c,e,d,f,...) and using the name of the phone itself for the path does not work. (
I tried to use the path that I can get from windows explorer which is "`This PC\Myphone`").

Example of the code:

```
Dim myobj As New FileSystemObject

Private Sub Command1_Click()
myobj.CopyFile "(My phone path which I don't know what is it)", "C:\New folder\(The name of the file that I want to copy)", True
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail? What kind of phone? Is it a USB connection?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the phone is from Samsung, Which name is Grand 2, And yes the connection is by USB

Comment: These are not using VB6, but seem to be trying to do essentially the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927475/windows-how-to-enumerate-all-connected-usb-devices-device-path  and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615750/how-can-the-directory-of-a-usb-drive-connected-to-a-system-be-obtained/22621218#22621218