# Can we get the path of a USB drive programmatically(Python) that is connected to a raspberry pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am currently working on a small project on Raspberry Pi. I want to make my project as automated as possible. I have a code that saves videos to a USB drive. However, for it to work, I have to hardcode the path of the drive. What I am trying to do is to get a code that will automatically get the path of the USB drive connected to the pi and the videos will be saved to that USB drive. Is it possible? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can the directory of a usb drive connected to a system be obtained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615750/how-can-the-directory-of-a-usb-drive-connected-to-a-system-be-obtained)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. It is what I was searching.