# Manufacturer String and Product string for a USB Mass storage device

Tags: windows, usb, win32gui, usb-mass-storage

I want to extract the manufacturer string and product string for a specific Mass storage USB device let's say C:. I am able to extract manufacturer string  and product string by enumerating all USB devices but now I don't know how to associate specific USB drive to manufacturer ID and Product ID. I am on Windows platform and using Visual Studio for development.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Farooq-

Comment: I think this should be helpful to you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733206/find-which-drive-corresponds-to-which-usb-mass-storage-device-in-winxp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this sample to find the corresponding device node for your mounted drive:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/RemoveDriveByLetter.aspx

Then, query the device using `SetupDiGetDeviceProperty` (using the `SPDRP_Xxx` identifiers as defined in Setupapi.h).