# Detect USB and copy *.* to USB drive using batch script

Tags: batch-file, usb

I am trying to write a batch script to detect a USB drive and, if it is plugged in,
for example copy *c:\test\big.txt* to the USB drive, and looping to detect another flash drive.

Comment: do you want to copy files or direcotries?

Answer (score 10):

```
@echo off
for %%d in (D: E: F: G: H: I: etc...) do (
   if exist %%d\nul (
      echo USB at drive %%d connected
   )
)
```

**EDIT**: Below is the right way to do that:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('fsutil fsinfo drives') do (
   for %%c in (%%b) do (
      for /F "tokens=3" %%d in ('fsutil fsinfo drivetype %%c') do (
         if %%d equ Removable (
            echo Drive %%c is Removable (USB^)
         )
      )
   )
)
```

Comment: How do you know which one is a USB drive?

Comment: Another alternative is to use Microsoft's [DevCon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) utility.

Comment: @StephenNiedzielski: I see no reason to download and use an additional application if the problem may be solved with the installed commands. On the other hand, I reviewed DevCon description at that link and I can't find the way to identify the USB drives. Could you show us an example of how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: @Aacini I ran out of room for a comment, so I've posted below.

Comment: Is there any way to do the second option without administrator privileges?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but....

```
@echo off

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 2^>NUL`) do (

if %%l equ 2 (
copy c:\test\big.txt %%i
        )
        )
```

This is assuming of course both drives are inserted.

Answer (score 1):

The above code had a flaw which has been attended to in the following code
The code works in XP and gives you the USB drive letters, if no usb device
is connected , it tells you so !

:: SUCCESS @ 2:39 AM ON 12 OCT 2013 !!!
:: IMPROVED BY BOBBY GOREJA

```
@echo off

set usbdrv=
set usb=No
:: Above two lines on 12 Oct 2013

fsutil fsinfo drives >de
type de | find "Drives:" /v >dlist

for /F "tokens=1" %%c in ('type dlist') do (

               for /F "tokens=3" %%d in ('fsutil fsinfo drivetype %%c') do (

               rem echo Token is %%d

             if %%d equ Removable (

            echo Drive %%c is Removable (USB^)

             set usbletter=%%c 
             set usb=Yes

            echo USB drive letter is %usbletter%

rem     set usbdrv = %%c   <<< this does NOT work!
 rem              echo USB1 drive letter is %usbdrv%

                                                                )
                                         )
                                    )
 del de
 del dlist

             echo  REPEAT:Device at %usbletter%

if  "%usb%"=="No" echo No USB Device Connected .
set usb=
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aacini I don't have a good setup to this case today, so I instead tried finding my USB webcam. I used `devmgmt.msc` and `devcon listclasses` to figure out the membership a connected USB camera would have. After a few tests, I arrived at `devcon find =Image USB\*`. I figured it would be simple enough to do the same for a USB mass storage device, so I tried `devcon find =Volume` (per listclasses). Unfortunately, this dumps out a GUID which you would then have to map to a drive letter. A cursory glance at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733206/find-which-drive-corresponds-to-which-usb-mass-storage-device-in-winxp) overflow suggests you can do so from the registry using `reg query`, but it seems at this point that `fsutil` would be simplest for your case.