# How Do I Eject a Volume in Java?

Tags: java, usb-drive

How can I "eject" a volume with Java, cross platform?

I have a program that does some operations on a removable drive (USB memory card reader), and once it's done, I want the program to eject/unmount/remove (depending which os lingo we're talking in) the memory card.

Is there a reliable cross-platform method of doing this?

Comment: Not with the standard library. You may have to resort to platform specific hacks. Did you have any particular operating system in mind?

Comment: There is no routine in the standard runtime library.  You will need to ask the underlying operating system to do so.

Comment: Here is a few Windows command line apps, use Process.execute to call it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206248/how-do-you-programmatically-eject-an-usb-mass-storage-device

Answer (score 2):

Probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but...

No.

To my knowledge, there isn't an established single-platform way of doing this.  For that matter, I've never come across a Java way of doing this.  A [rather scary C# CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/usbeject.aspx) does allow ejecting devices, but only on Windows.

The [various](http://javax-usb.org/), [depressingly poor](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/), Java USB libraries don't even hint at ejecting devices.  They don't work across all platforms, so even if they did it wouldn't help you.

My suggestion: gin up some scripts or executables for each platform, and then just spin up a Process as needed.

Comment: Or wrap some OS-specific code in JNI. But I'm sure this is the 'hard way'.

Comment: I'd only consider JNI if performance is important.  If 'eject usb' is in an inner loop somewhere, it might be worth it.  Then again, that'd raise... interesting questions.

Answer (score 1):

A litle late response but i thought it was worth sharing...
Since the default Java API does not come with this feature on it, you could use external libraries as mentioned above, however i personally found it much more convenient (for windows) to have a third party exe file in the jar's classpath, extract it in the temp folder, execute it when needed and then remove it once the aplication is done with it.
As a third party program i used [this](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html) which is a CLI only program that can do a few tricks with connected devices, and then used this code:

```
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(program),TEMP_EJECT_PROGRAM);
```

to export it to the temp file location (Using ApacheIO, you can definately do without it), and this code:

```
    private void safelyRemoveDrive(final String driveLetter) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (TEMP_EJECT_PROGRAM.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Removing " + driveLetter);
                try {
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime()
                            .exec("\"" + TEMP_EJECT_PROGRAM.toString() + "\" " + driveLetter + " -L");
                    p.waitFor();
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
                    while (s.hasNextLine())
                        System.out.println(s.nextLine());
                    s.close();
                    System.out.println("Removed " + driveLetter + ".");
                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

to remove the drive. The pieces of code above are definately not suited for all aplications and the second one in perticular is not the greatest, there are other much better ways to do it than spawning an anonymus thread... Still however you get the idea behind it :)

Lastly, I sugest you inform the user appropriately and ask for their concent before executing any third-party software in their machine...

I hope this was helpful :-)

Comment: Which did you use?

Comment: The removal of drives zip?